# How can I find out which radio button is selected using jQuery without searching for the radio group each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I know I can use something described here: [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

i.e. `jQuery("input[name=myradiogroup]:checked").val()` to get the selected radio button value.  But I'd like to cache the radio group and determine which value is selected at a later point in time.

I want to do something like:

```
var myRadio = jQuery("input[name=myradiogroup]");
//some code
var value = myRadio.getCheckedButton().val();
```

Any way to do this or do I have to explicitly run the selector with `:checked` in it every time I want to find out the selected value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var myRadio = jQuery("input[name=myradiogroup]");
var selectedRadio = myRadio.filter(":checked");
alert( selectedRadio.val() );
```

Comment: Hmm, that's odd... I saw an answer like that in the linked question but I couldn't get it to work.  I'll try again, but it seems like .find is searching for child elements, ignoring the radio group itself, so I always get an empty result.

Comment: `find` will only look in descendants, so it will return an empty set since the checkbox elements have no descendants and calling `val` on that empty set will return `undefined`

Comment: Whoops, should be filter. That is what I get for answering and eating at the same time. Altered the code.

Answer (score 4):

Could do

```
myRadio.filter(':checked').val()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myValue="";
$('input[name=myradiogroup]').change(function() {
     myValue= this.value;
    alert(myValue);
});
```

Now you can check "myValue" anytime you wish.