# Jquery Index reporting wrong index

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
            <div id="radioButtonSet">
                <input type="radio" id="radio-value" name="dataChange" value="value" checked="checked" ><label for="radio-value">Value</label>
                <input type="radio" id="radio-percentage" name="dataChange" value="percent" ><label for="radio-percentage">Percentage</label>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=dataChange]").on("change", function(){
  console.log($("input[type=radio][name=dataChange]").filter(":checked").index())
});
```

I expect the indices to be 0 and 1, but they are 0 and 2. Why?

Demo: http://jsbin.com/xifutarumu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/): "If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements."

```
<div id="radioButtonSet">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-value" name="dataChange" value="value" checked="checked" >
    <label for="radio-value">Value</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-percentage" name="dataChange" value="percent" >
    <label for="radio-percentage">Percentage</label>
</div>
```

The `radio-percentage` input is the third of its siblings, and therefore has an index of two.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming sibling would be of the same filter type so only siblings that are `input[type=radio][name=dataChange]`

Comment: You can achieve that by doing something like `$("input[type=radio][name=dataChange]").index(':checked')`; consult the linked docs for more details

Comment: For future googlers, the solution was `$("input[type=radio][name=dataChange]").index($("input[type=radio][name=dataChange]").filter(':checked'))`  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395537/jquery-how-to-get-the-index-of-a-checked-radio-button

Comment: or `$("input[type=radio][name=dataChange]").index(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Passing `this` as the context for `index()` seems to produce the desired results. *shrug*

```
$("input").index(this);
```

See http://jsbin.com/wuzoxocura/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: If you remove the label between 2 radiobuttons, the index method return the right index

Comment: Right, I didn't notice there were additional elements. Nicely spotted, sir

Answer (score 0):

It is showing correctly index as

0:first input

1:label just after 1 input

2:second input