# javascript/jquery- how to determine if a list/checkbox allows multiple values to be selected or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse through a typical form using jquery. I want to obtain all details about the various fields in the form- viz field name, field type (eg radio/checkbox/list)...

How do I determine if a field allows multiple values to be selected? (eg in check box or list box)?

If this cannot be done using jquery, then can it be done using pure javascript? I already have with me a ref to the element for which this (whether multiple values are allowed or not) has to be determined...

Comment: If you have a set of checkboxes, you can always select multiple values, unless it is somehow prevent through JavaScript (though radio buttons would be more appropriate then) and I don't think you will be able to find that out (you could simulate selecting the boxes though and see how many are really selected). For a `select` list, check whether it has the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: @FelixKling - pls put your comment as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your control with some `<div>`   as:

```
<div id="testCheck">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" />
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2" />
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="3" />
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="4" />
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="5" />
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="6" />
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="7" />
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="8" />
    </div>
```

and check the selected or unselected elements using follwwing jquery code snippet. `.size()` will return the no of checked item and you can get the value of selected items by .val().

//Write your code when Document is loaded or some element click

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#testChk").click(function() {
                    alert($("#testCheck :checked").size());
                    //function to print the value of each checked checkboxes
                    $("#testCheck :checked").each(function() {
                        alert("value = " + $(this).val());   
                });
```

for more help follow these links:

[How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

have a look on jquery selector. you should watch bottom itms :password, :reset etc that you need to use. 
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

[http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.ht](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html)ml

[Handling Checkboxes, Radio Buttons and Select Options in jQuery](http://jivebay.com/2007/05/30/handling-checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-select-options-in-jquery/)

Hope this help you little bit...

Comment: @NiranjanKala- thank you for the exhaustive and well researched answer you have provided...unfortunately I have no control over the div... Hence I will have to settle for the answer provided by Felix Kling. Thank you though for your help...