# Javascript, radio buttons and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, radio-button, checked

I am generating multiple buttons using PHP:

```
<form name="submit_form" id="submit_form" action="">

<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {?>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="<?php echo $value[$i]; ?>"/>$value[$i]<?php }?>
</form>
```

I have problem checking if radio button is selected using Javascript since it keeps returning 'undefined'

I am accessing radio buttons (before ) using javascript in this way:

```
    alert(document.forms["submit_form"].elements["answer"].checked);
```

I have tried echoing whole html, same thing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByName(name);` - This method return a nodeList.

```
list=document.getElementsByName("answer");

alert(list.item(0).checked); //1st
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery....

To get the value of the selected radioName item of a form called 'myForm':

$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()

[How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: Or better: [Don't](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?198014) [use](http://www.artefactgroup.com/#/content/want-a-faster-html5-webapp-dont-use-jquery/) [jQuery](http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2011/10/22/don-t-use-jquery-to-write-a-web-application-part-1/) (at least for simple things)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid jQuery. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("answer")` and your `document.forms`-approach both return an array (correct: a NodeList) of <input> elements. You will have to loop through them and check each for the `checked` property.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I'll probably loop through them