# How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery under IE7 and IE8?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-selectors

Base on this question [radio selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

I use this way

```
<input type="radio" class="fp" value="q" name="fp" checked>
fp = $('input[name=fp]:checked').val();
alert(fp);
```

To get the value of select radio box. Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cjK7/5/)

**But it is not worked under IE7 and IE8. Always got "*Object doesn't support this property or method*" . Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to set your value into a variable, as shown:

```
var fp = $("input[name='fp']:checked").val();
alert(fp);
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5cjK7/21/)**

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable before using it:

http://jsfiddle.net/5cjK7/13/

```
var fp = $('input[name=fp]:checked').val();

alert(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

IE can have unexpected behaviour with the pseudo selectors use `attr` or `prop`(1.6+)

```
fp = $("input[name='fp']").filter(function(){return $(this).attr("checked");}).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem really simple, but I believe the issue deals with the fact that you are assigning the value to a variable named "fp" which happens to match the name of the form element.  Internet Explorer already has a variable in scope named "fp" which is the radio button element itself.  Assigning a string value to that variable is not allowed.  You can solve this one of two ways:

```
// Declare a new variable
var fp = $('input[name=fp]:checked').val();
alert(fp);
```

or ...

```
// Assign to a new variable in global scope (not recommended)
xy = $('input[name=fp]:checked').val();
alert(xy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your inout element and the attr. `checked` should have a value like;

```
<input type="radio" class="fp" value="q" name="fp" checked="checked" />
```

Also;
- You need to declare the variable before you use it.
- The jQuery selector should contain quotes.
- The selector returns a collection of elements so you should extract the first hit, perhaps by using `first()`.

```
var fp = $('input[name="fp"]:checked').first().val();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this behavior because the form submission called a function which replaced the form's html and then checked for the checked item:

```
var sizeSelected = $(this).find("input[name='size']:checked").val();
```

In hindsight it's strange this works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but it does. Only IE/Edge bonks with `sizeSelected == null`. The solution is to check the form results before clearing/replacing the form's html.