# jQuery get value of selected radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button, siebel

The problem statement is simple. I need to see if user has selected a radio button from a radio group. Every radio button in the group share same id.

The problem is that I don't have control on how the form is generated. Here is the sample code of how a radio button control code looks like:

```
<input type="radio" name='s_2_1_6_0' value='Mail copy to my bill to address' id = "InvCopyRadio" onchange = 'SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm2_0,s_4,"","1-DPWJJF")' style="height:20;width:25" tabindex=1997 >
```

In addition to this when a radio button is selected it doesn't add a "checked" attribute to the control just text **checked** *(I guess just the property checked without a value)*. Below is how a selected radio control looks like

```
<input type="radio" checked name='s_2_1_6_0' value='Mail copy to my bill to address' id = "InvCopyRadio" onchange = 'SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm2_0,s_4,"","1-DPWJJF")' style="height:20;width:25" tabindex=1997 >
```

Can anybody help me with jQuery code that can help me to get the value of checked radio button?

Comment: You've got multiple elements with the same ID? That's... terrible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: How does that work with them all having the same ID? When evaluating by ID doesn't the evaluation stop at the first matched element? What's the purpose here are they dynamic elements shown at different times?

Comment: FYI, ASP.NET MVC's @Html.RadioButtonFor helper will generate all radio buttons with the same id.  oops.

Comment: try my solution that is best in all solutions. :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button/70798467#70798467

Answer (score 1658):

Just use.

```
$('input[name="name_of_your_radiobutton"]:checked').val();
```

It is that easy.

Comment: Do not forget the quote signs:
$("input[name='" + fieldName + "']:checked").val();

Comment: Why does this return "on" rather than the value I've specified in the HTML? EDIT:  Because I didn't have quotes around my values.

Comment: $('input[name="name_of_your_radiobutton"]:checked').val();

Comment: Note that if no button is selected this will just return `null`, which is logical but sometimes can confuse you when you're used to seeing `""` as the default value via the `.val()` call.

Comment: @xji - Under normal practice, a radio button is a group of 'selectables" and one of the choices will be selected by default before being displayed. So no confusion.

Comment: @user12379095 Is it? For a new record, if there is no default selection and the user has to choose, it usually is unselected. This forces the user to make a decision and forgotten wrong defaults won't go unnoticed.

Comment: This is correct but, for those who want to get the script size as small as possible then you can use a class on each of your radio buttons (example class="mo") and then use $(".mo:checked").val();  It depends of course on how many radio buttons you have.  If, like me, you watch every byte of data you throw at a user then its useful to know both approaches.

Comment: @Pete-iCalculator yes that is possible. It is just an approach, modifications are always possible.

Answer (score 353):

First, you cannot have multiple elements with the same id.  I know you said you can't control how the form is created, but...try to somehow remove all the ids from the radios, or make them unique.

To get the value of the selected radio button, select it by name with the `:checked` filter.

```
var selectedVal = "";
var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='s_2_1_6_0']:checked");
if (selected.length > 0) {
    selectedVal = selected.val();
}
```

**EDIT**

So you have no control over the names.  In that case I'd say put these radio buttons all inside a div, named, say, `radioDiv`, then slightly modify your selector:

```
var selectedVal = "";
var selected = $("#radioDiv input[type='radio']:checked");
if (selected.length > 0) {
    selectedVal = selected.val();
}
```

Comment: Sure you can have multiple elements with the same ID. It's forbidden, and you can't use those IDs, but it's totally possible and you can still use the elements and address them by other means, like you showed.

Comment: how do you do this by class name? is that possible?

Answer (score 92):

Simplest way to get the selected radio button's value is as follows:

```
$("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();
```

No space should be used in between selector.

Comment: **The most straightforward option, this is.**

Answer (score 52):

```
$("#radioID") // select the radio by its id
    .change(function(){ // bind a function to the change event
        if( $(this).is(":checked") ){ // check if the radio is checked
            var val = $(this).val(); // retrieve the value
        }
    });
```

Make sure to wrap this in the DOM ready function (`$(function(){...});` or `$(document).ready(function(){...});`).

Comment: I am always getting a blank value with this code.. I guess this is due to the fact that I don't have property with value checked just a text checked (I am not sure if we can consider it a property)

Comment: Are you selecting the radio button by its ID? Did you change `radioID` to its ID?

Answer (score 43):

```
<input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="numbers" value="1" />1<br/>
<input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="numbers" value="2" />2<br/>
<input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="numbers" value="3" />3<br/>
```

This will return, checked radio button value.

```
if($("input[type='radio'].radioBtnClass").is(':checked')) {
    var card_type = $("input[type='radio'].radioBtnClass:checked").val();
    alert(card_type);
}
```

More details in my blog: https://webexplorar.com/jquery-get-selected-radio-button-value/

Comment: For who couldn't get the input's value; need to set the same names on them and then set the values as 1,2,3.. If you dont set the value, you get "on" as default value. This answer helped me.

Answer (score 37):

1. In your code, jQuery just looks for the first instance of an input
   with name q12_3, which in this case has a value of 1. You want an
   input with name q12_3 that is `:checked`.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {     
        alert($("input[name=q12_3]:checked").val());
    });
});
```

2. Note that the above code is not the same as using
   `.is(":checked")`.
   jQuery's `is()` 
   function returns a boolean (true or false) and not an
   element.

Answer (score 26):

This code works.

```
var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23053203/2227743) from 2014, with just a different button name. Several other answers also mention this. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Answer (score 24):

Get all radios:

```
var radios = $("input[type='radio']");
```

Filter to get the one that's checked

```
radios.filter(":checked");
```

***OR***

Another way you can find radio button value

```
var RadeoButtonStatusCheck = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
```

Comment: I use `$('[name=your_inputs_names]:checked').val()` cause they always have same unique name

Comment: Good use of `.filter()`

Comment: That `.filter()`. I wish this answer can be at the top.

Comment: This is by far the best answer on this entire page. OP asks how to get one radio out of a group of radios. None of the answers above work when your radio buttons have unique ID's (which is how it goes unless you have only 1 ?)

Answer (score 24):

```
 $("input[name='gender']:checked").val()
```

for nested attributes

```
$("input[name='lead[gender]']:checked").val()
```

Don't forget single braces for name

Answer (score 18):

To get the value of the selected Radio Button, Use RadioButtonName and the Form Id containing the RadioButton.

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

OR by only

```
$('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 13):

> Check the example it works fine

```html
<div class="dtl_radio">
  Metal purity : 
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="purityradio" class="gold_color" value="92" checked="">
    92 %
  </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="purityradio" class="gold_color" value="75">
    75 %
  </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="purityradio" class="gold_color" value="58.5">
    58.5 %
  </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="purityradio" class="gold_color" value="95">
    95 %
  </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="purityradio" class="gold_color" value="59">
    59 %
  </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="purityradio" class="gold_color" value="76">
    76 %
  </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="purityradio" class="gold_color" value="93">
    93 %
  </label>
   </div>
```

```js
var check_value = $('.gold_color:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 12):

Use Below Code

```
$('input[name=your_radio_button_name]:checked').val();
```

Please note, value attribute should be defined so could get "Male" or "Female" in your result.

```
<div id='div_container'>
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" /> Male <br />
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" /> Female
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

See below for working example with a collection of radio groups each associated with different sections. Your naming scheme is important, but ideally you should try and use a consistent naming scheme for inputs anyway (especially when they're in sections like here).

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var section = $('input:radio[name="sec_num"]:checked').val();
  var question = $('input:radio[name="qst_num"]:checked').val();
  
  var selectedVal = checkVal(section, question);
  $('#show_val_div').text(selectedVal);
  $('#show_val_div').show();
});

function checkVal(section, question) {
  var value = $('input:radio[name="sec'+section+'_r'+question+'"]:checked').val() || "Selection Not Made";
  return value;
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; }
div { margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px; }
h5, label { display: inline-block; }
.small { font-size: 12px; }
.hide { display: none; }
#formDiv { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
.center { display:block; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="center">
  <div>
    <h4>Section 1</h4>

    <h5>First question text</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec1_r1" value="(1:1) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec1_r1" value="(1:1) NO"> NO</label>
    <br/>
    <h5>Second question text</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec1_r2" value="(1:2) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec1_r2" value="(1:2) NO"> NO</label>
    <br/>
    <h5>Third Question</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec1_r3" value="(1:3) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec1_r3" value="(1:3) NO"> NO</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <h5>First question text</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec2_r1" value="(2:1) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec2_r1" value="(2:1) NO"> NO</label>
    <br/>
    <h5>Second question text</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec2_r2" value="(2:2) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec2_r2" value="(2:2) NO"> NO</label>
    <br/>
    <h5>Third Question</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec2_r3" value="(2:3) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec2_r3" value="(2:3) NO"> NO</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h4>Section 3</h4>
    <h5>First question text</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec3_r1" value="(3:1) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec3_r1" value="(3:1) NO"> NO</label>
    <br/>
    <h5>Second question text</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec3_r2" value="(3:2) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec3_r2" value="(3:2) NO"> NO</label>
    <br/>
    <h5>Third Question</h5>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec3_r3" value="(3:3) YES"> YES</label>
    <label class="small"><input type="radio" name="sec3_r3" value="(3:3) NO"> NO</label>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="formDiv" class="center">
  <form target="#show_val_div" method="post">
    <p>Choose Section Number</p>
    <label class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="sec_num" value="1"> 1</label>
    <label class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="sec_num" value="2"> 2</label>
    <label class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="sec_num" value="3"> 3</label>
    <br/><br/>
    
    <p>Choose Question Number</p>
    <label class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="qst_num" value="1"> 1</label>
    <label class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="qst_num" value="2"> 2</label>
    <label class="small">
      <input type="radio" name="qst_num" value="3"> 3</label>
    <br/><br/>
    
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Show Value">
    
  </form>
  <br/>
  <p id="show_val_div"></p>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the parent form to find the radio input value. You don't know how the form is generating but you can give class to the form.

```
$('.form_class input[type=radio]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if (!$("#InvCopyRadio").prop("checked") && $("#InvCopyRadio").prop("checked"))
    // do something
```

Comment: Why bother doing the string comparison to `undefined` when you know for certain the value must be `checked`? There's no need in jQuery.

Comment: In the question I don't see any info suggesting that one radio button will be checked from the start. I mean it's like that in most cases with radio buttons. So in the case when we'd have to check that and none were selected, attr("checked") would return a null object.

Comment: Right, but I just meant returning null wouldn't cause an error so the comparison to `"undefined"` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a shorter version of getting value of selected radio button

```js
var value = $(":radio:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this with example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1  /jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="first"/> 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="second"/> 2 <br/>
</form>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').on('click', function () {
        var value = $("[name=radio]:checked").val();

        alert(value);
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

By Name only

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="EventType"]:radio').change(function () {
        alert($("input[name='EventType']:checked").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

> You can get the value of selected radio button by Id using this in javascript/jQuery.

```
$("#InvCopyRadio:checked").val();
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: very efficient !!

Comment: This assumes having at least 2 elements with same ID - which is not correct and some browsers will report warrning into console. You need to assign unique ID to each radio button and traverse through them by calling each ID.

Comment: @lubosdz Yes, we should not have 2 elements with the same ID. But, as you check the question. The user has selected a radio button from a radio group. Every radio button in the group shares the same id. So in that case this works fine.

Comment: To elaborate,Radio button concept fails as radio buttons are provided as multiple options, only one to select... Set of Radio buttons or checkboxes must not have same Id.
A single web page can have only one unique ID through out the page.

Answer (score 6):

I know that I am joining this late. But it is worth mentioning that it takes

```
<label class="custom-control-label" for="myRadioBtnName">Personal Radio Button</label>
```

And then I checked this in my js. It could be like

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$("#MyRadioBtnOuterDiv").click(function(){
    var radioValue = $("input[name=myRadioButtonNameAttr]:checked").val();
    if(radioValue === "myRadioBtnName"){
        $('#showMyRadioArea').show();
    }else if(radioValue === "yourRadioBtnName"){
        $('#showYourRadioArea').show();
    }
});
});
```

`

Answer (score 4):

The best way to explain this simple topic is by giving simple example and reference link:-

> In the following example we have two radio buttons. If the user selects any radio button, we will display the selected radio button value in a alert box.

Html:

```
<form id="Demo">
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" /> Male <br />
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" /> Female<br />
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="others" /> others <br />
</form>
```

jquery:-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Demo input').on('change', function() {
            alert($('input[name="Gender"]:checked', '#Demo').val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="subscriptions">
 Company Suscription: <input type="radio" name="subsrad" value="1">
 Customer Subscription:<input type="radio" name="subsrad" value="2">
 Manully Set:<input type="radio" name="subsrad" value="MANUAL">
 NO Subscription:<input type="radio" name="subsrad" value="0">
 </div>
```

and handle jquery for alert as for th e value set / Changed through div id:

```
$("#subscriptions input") // select the radio by its id
    .on('change', function(){ // bind a function to the change event
    alert($('input[name="subsrad"]:checked', '#subscriptions').val());
            });
```

it is so easy....:-}

Comment: A simpler way to do this using the parent id would be.... 
$("#subscriptions").on( "change", function() {  
    var selection = $(this).find("input:checked").val();
    alert( selection );  
});

Answer (score 2):

I am not a javascript person, but I found here for searching this problem. For who google it and find here, I am hoping that this helps some. So, as in question if we have a list of radio buttons:

```
<div class="list">
    <input type="radio" name="b1" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="b2" value="2" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" name="b3" value="3">
</div>
```

I can find which one selected with this selector:

```
$('.list input[type="radio"]:checked:first').val();
```

Even if there is no element selected, I still don't get undefined error. So, you don't have to write extra if statement before taking element's value.

Here is very basic [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rz95r1d3/).

Comment: This is an incorrect use of the name attribute for radio inputs. Radio buttons in a group must have the same name if you are only wanting to allow for a single value from the group. Doing it this way makes it work like checkboxes, allowing for multiple selections instead of a single selection within the group.

Comment: @MistyDawn you're right, I don't even remember how did I wrote this, probably it's from fixing a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 radio buttons namely rd1 and Radio1

```
<input type="radio" name="rd" id="rd1" />
<input type="radio" name="rd" id="Radio1" />
```

The simplest wayt to check which radio button is checked ,by checking individual is(":checked")  property

```
if ($("#rd1").is(":checked")) {
      alert("rd1 checked");
   }
 else {
      alert("rd1 not checked");
   }
```

Comment: This is not a very robust solution. It's better to just have a containing div, and then look at all the radios under it and select the checked on. You could also look at all radios with a certain name, and then find the checked one. This reduces having to change the code every time a button is added.

Comment: If your page has any more than 2 radio inputs this could get VERY confusing and assigning an id to every single radio would be very time consuming. This method would not typically be considered good practice.

Answer (score 2):

### Another Easy way to understand... It's Working:

**HTML Code:**

```
 <input type="radio" name="active_status" class="active_status" value="Hold">Hold 
 <input type="radio" name="active_status" class="active_status" value="Cancel">Cancel 
 <input type="radio" name="active_status" class="active_status" value="Suspend">Suspend
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".active_status", function () {
 var a = $('input[name=active_status]:checked').val();  
 (OR)   
 var a = $('.active_status:checked').val();
 alert(a);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

multi group radio button covert value to array

```js
var arr = [];
    function r(n) {


        var section = $('input:radio[name="' + n + '"]:checked').val();
        arr[n] = section;

        console.log(arr)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" onchange="r('b1')" class="radioID" name="b1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" onchange="r('b1')"  class="radioID" name="b1" value="2"  >2
<input type="radio" onchange="r('b1')"   class="radioID" name="b1" value="3">3

<br>

<input type="radio" onchange="r('b2')" class="radioID2" name="b2" value="4">4
<input type="radio" onchange="r('b2')"  class="radioID2" name="b2" value="5"  >5
<input type="radio" onchange="r('b2')"   class="radioID2" name="b2" value="6">6
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation, so more people can understand.

Answer (score 2):

Even `input` is not necessary as suggested by other answers. 
The following code can also be used:

```
var variable_name = $("[name='radio_name']:checked").val();
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23053203/215552) from five years ago, just without the `input` and with unnecessary quote marks.

Comment: Those quotes are not unnecessary and the reason I have posted the above answer is to let people know that input ain't necessary

Comment: Then you should consider [edit]ing your question to mention those reasons rather than using the command "Use the following code". You may wish to reference a source that says the quotes are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
HTML Code
<input id="is_verified" class="check" name="is_verified" type="radio" value="1"/>
<input id="is_verified" class="check" name="is_verified" type="radio" checked="checked" value="0"/>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />

Javascript Code
$("input[type='radio'].check").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $("#submit").val("Verified & Save");
        }else{
            $("#submit").val("Save");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML Markup :**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="rdMale" type="radio" class="clsGender" value="Male" name="rdGender" /> Male
  <input id="rdFemale" type="radio" class="clsGender" value="Female" name="rdGender" /> Female
 </div>
```

---

**Get selected value by radio button Id:**

```
 $("input[name='rdGender']").click(function () {
     alert($("#rdMale").val());
});
```

---

**Get value by radiobutton Classname**

```
 $(".clsGender").click(function () {
       alert($(this).val());
            //or
      alert($(".clsGender:checked").val());
   });
```

---

**Get value by name**

```
   $("input[name='rdGender']").click(function () {
          var rdVaule = $("input[name='rdGender']:checked").val();
          alert(rdVaule);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple radio buttons, you have to put same name attribute on your radio button tag.
For example;

```
<input type="radio" name"gender" class="select_gender" value="male">
<input type="radio" name"gender" class="select_gender" value="female">
```

Once you have radio options, now you can do jQuery code like below to get he value of selected/checked radio option.

```
$(document).on("change", ".select_gender", function () {
   console.log($(this).val());    // Here you will get the current selected/checked radio option value
});
```

Note: $(document) is used because if the radio button are created after DOM 100% loaded, then you need it, because if you don't use $(document) then jQuery will not know the scope of newly created radion buttons. It's a good practice to do jQuery event calls like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="radio" name='s_2_1_6_0' value='Mail copy to my bill to address' id = "InvCopyRadio" onchange = 'SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm2_0,s_4,"","1-DPWJJF")' style="height:20;width:25" tabindex=1997 >

$(function() {
      $("#submit").click(function() {
        alert($('input[name=s_2_1_6_0]:checked').val());
      });
    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know the sepcific name or want to check all radio inputs in a form, you can use a global var to check for each radio group the value only once:
`

```
        var radio_name = "";
        $("form).find(":radio").each(function(){
            if (!radio_name || radio_name != $(this).attr('name')) {
                radio_name = $(this).attr('name');
                var val = $('input[name="'+radio_name+'"]:checked').val();
                if (!val) alert($('input[name="'+radio_name+'"]:checked').val());
            }
        });`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-radio">
       <input class="radio-outlined" id="accept_new_login1" type="radio" name="aNL" value="1">
       <label for="accept_new_login1" class="radio-teal">Yes</label>
        <input class="radio-outlined" id="accept_new_login2" type="radio" name="aNL" value="0">
        <label for="accept_new_login2" class="radio-teal">No</label>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("input[name=aNL]").on("click" , function () {
    console.log("test" ,$("#accept_new_login").val() , this.value , this.id );
  })

 </script>
```

This Solution is not only easy also tells selected ID and thats value. you can check my output.

[image]