# identifier for value of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<form name="send">
<input type="radio" name="schoose" value="24">
<input type="radio" name="schoose" value="25">
<input type="radio" name="schoose" value="26">
```

I am trying to find the value of the selected radio button I thought it was

```
document.send.schoose.value
```

apparently I was wrong, can someone clue me in

Comment: Check here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8622351/1519323

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option...

```
$('input[name=schoose]:checked').val()
```

Comment: chosen as the most versatile with the least coding

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementsByName('schoose')[1].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

try the `$("input[name='schoose']:checked").val();`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by

with javascript

```
  document.getElementsByName('schoose')[1].value;
```

and with jquery like below

```
$("[name=schoose]").each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        if (selection == 'default') {
            // Do something
        }
        else {
            // Do something else
        }             
    });
});
```

or

```
$("input:radio[name=schoose]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
  //or
  var val = $('input:radio[name=schoose]:checked').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript you can get the values of the second radio button with:

```
document.getElementsByName('schoose')[1].value;
```

In jQuery:

```
$('input[name="schoose"]:eq(1)').val();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NZAJh/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('schoose')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

With just javascript:

```
    var radio=document.getElementsByName('schoose');

    var radioValue="";
    var length=radio.length;

    for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
       if(radio[i].checked==true) radioValue=radio[i].value;
    }
    alert(radioValue);
```