# mvc form collection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am facing a weird problem. I have a cshtml form:

```
  <label class="pre_req_questions_width">
                    @Html.RadioButton("radioGroup" + Model.ID, "1", (Model.ExpectedResponse == 1 ? true : false), new { id = "rbtnYes", style = "margin-top:0px; margin-right:10px;" })Yes</label>
                <label class="pre_req_questions_width">
                    @Html.RadioButton("radioGroup" + Model.ID, "2", !(Model.ExpectedResponse == 1 ? true : false), new { id = "rbtnNo", style = "margin-top:0px;margin-right:10px;" })No</label>
```

On form submit, I am getting radio group value like this:

```
int radioValue =  int.Parse(fc.GetValue(controlID).AttemptedValue);
```

It works fine when i call it from `@Html.BeginForm()`, but when i try to send form collection via ajax like this:

```
input = $(':input')

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("SavePrerequisiteQuestion", "Dashboard", new { id = @Model.ID })',
            data: input,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (msg) {
             alert("fine");
            }, error: function (req, status, error) {
                    // with error   
                    alert(error);
                }
        });
```

It send both values like this "1,2" rather than sending just selected/submitted value.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request, you're sending all `:input` elements as your data:

```
...
data: input
...
```

What you probably want is to just [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form data, and send it with the request:

```
...
data: input.closest('form').serialize()
...
```

This is assuming you have your radio buttons in a `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be so easy to work around this.  For instance, to get a selected radio button, you can do this: [jQuery get value of selected radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

So you can't just take all inputs and get the values from them... instead, you have to have more of a selective approach, and handle different elements appropriately.  Checkboxes and selects will also have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the @Html.Beginform back in and hijack the form submit in your jQuery

```
$('#formID').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  // Just to stop the automatic Non Ajax submission of the form

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
       //do stuff on success callback
       alert("fine");
    });
});
```

You can inherit the action path from the Html.BeginForm itself in the path below by doing
$(this).attr('action')
Note: If you want to manually put the path in there you still can instead of getting it 
from the form
Then use $(this).serialize() to just serialize the whole form like the person above me
suggested