# select radio with jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I need select value of radio, when I click on button.
This is my code. jquery code must start with this code:

```
$('.button').click(function(){});
```

I wrote this code but it not work:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var t = $(this).parent().find('td div#select_type').children('input[checked=checked]').html(); });

 <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td width="130">
                    <div id="select_type">
                        <input value="0" id="select_type_0" type="radio" name="select_type" />
                        <label for="select_type_0"></label>
                        <input value="1" id="select_type_1" type="radio" name="select_type" />
                        <label for="select_type_1"></label>
                        <input value="2" id="select_type_2" type="radio" name="select_type" checked=checked />
                        <label for="select_type_2"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="button button_bt" style=" border: none">
                    <a>button</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            ...
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: `.html` gets the content _inside_ an element (HTML code of child elements and text nodes) – `input` elements do not have any content “inside” of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of selected radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution**

```
var t = $(this).parent().find('td div#select_type').children('input:checked').val();alert(t);
```

**Demo**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/0cyfjpu2/)

Comment: rate it if my answer was useful

Comment: Thank You! I have another problem. I need select first td too when I click on button. I think I must use trigger. Can You help me?

Comment: alert($('.row td:eq (1)').html ());

Answer (score 0):

I cant find your mistake, but I can offer other solution

First lets give id to elements

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td id="form" width="130">
                <div id="select_type">
                    <input value="0" id="select_type_0" type="radio" name="select_type" />
                    <label for="select_type_0"></label>
                    <input value="1" id="select_type_1" type="radio" name="select_type" />
                    <label for="select_type_1"></label>
                    <input value="2" id="select_type_2" type="radio" name="select_type" checked=checked />
                    <label for="select_type_2"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="btn" class="button button_bt" style=" border: none">
                <a>button</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

than call jquery like this

```
$('.button').click(function(){
var t = $("#form input[type='radio']:checked").val();});
```

it will fork correctly

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$('.button > a').click(function(){
    var myValue= $('div#select_type input:radio:checked').val();
    alert(myValue);
});
```

also can find in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9svfxxj/)

Answer (score 0):

"prop" worked for me:

```
$("#element_id").prop("checked", true);
```

My html:

```
<input type="radio" id="on_the_first" name="recurrence-monthly-option" value="on_the_first" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" id="on_day_of_month" name="recurrence-monthly-option" value="on_day_of_month" />
```

I tried (but didn’t work):

```
$('input:radio[name=recurrence-monthly-option]:nth(0)').attr('checked', true);
$('input:radio[name=recurrence-monthly-option]:nth(1)').attr('checked', true);
$("#on_the_first").attr('checked', '');
```