# Using jQuery to check value of radio select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following some previously answered questions her on Stack Overflow I am trying to show a div if the 'Female' radio box is checked and hide if the 'Male' checkbox is checked - this is the code I am using and it doesn't seem to do anything:

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#genderSelect input:radio').click(function () {


        if (jQuery('#genderSelect input:radio').val() === 'Female') {
            jQuery(".joinFemaleForm").show("slow", function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        } else if (jQuery('#genderSelect input:radio').val() === 'Male') {
            jQuery(".joinFemaleForm").hide("slow", function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio" id="genderSelect">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><input type="radio" name="male-female" value="Male">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Male</span></span>
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><input type="radio" name="male-female" value="Female">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Female</span></span>
</span>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:checked` to get the element that is selected.

```
jQuery('#genderSelect input:radio:checked').val()
//                               ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code.

```
var checkval = $("#genderSelect").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
alert(checkval);
```