# Multiple Radio button call with jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I would like to make a simple quiz that checks for correct answers and counts the score which outputs on the bottom of the page. I was able to do it with simple js and html but would like to do the same using jquery. However when i press submit in jquery version nothing happens ( i am a noob to jquery and cant find what is wrong) Thanks in advance!

```js
//Question One Answer is 'a'
//Question One Answer is 'b'
//Question One Answer is 'b'
//Question One Answer is 'b'
//Question One Answer is 'a'

var score = 0;

checkAll = function() {

  var message;
  // var score = 0; 

  if ($("#question1").val() === "a") {
    score++;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  if ($("#question2").val() === "b") {
    score++;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  if ($("#question3").val() === "b") {
    score++;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  if ($("#question4").val() === "b") {
    score++;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  if ($("#question5").val() === "a") {
    score++;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  message = "You got " + score + "out of five questions right!";
  $("#results").html(message);

  initialize = function() {
    $("#init").click(checkAll)
  };
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Form Example</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="quiz.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Geography Quiz</h1>


  <p>
    <label for="user">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="user" />
  </p>
  <div class="qheader">
    <p> 1) Which of the countries below is largest by area?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="questsel">
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="question1">a) Russia<br>
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="question1">b) China<br>
    <input type="radio" value="c" name="question1">c) USA<br>
    <input type="radio" value="d" name="question1">d) Canada<br>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="qheader">
    <p> 2) Which of these cities is United States Capital?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="questsel">
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="question2">a) New York<br>
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="question2">b) Washington D.C
    <input type="radio" value="c" name="question2">c) Chicago<br>
    <input type="radio" value="d" name="question2">d) Moscow<br>
  </div>

  <div class="qheader">
    <p> 3) Which of these cities is Spain's Capital?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="questsel">
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="question3">a) Barcelona<br>
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="question3">b) Madrid <br>
    <input type="radio" value="c" name="question3">c) Milan<br>
    <input type="radio" value="d" name="question3">d) Rome<br>
  </div>

  <div class="qheader">
    <p> 4) Which ocean is the largest?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="questsel">
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="question4">a) Arctic<br>
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="question4">b) Pacific<br>
    <input type="radio" value="c" name="question4">c) Indian<br>
    <input type="radio" value="d" name="question4">d) Atlantic<br>
  </div>

  <div class="qheader">
    <p> 5) Which of these rivers is largest in North America?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="questsel">
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="question5">a) Missouri River<br>
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="question5">b) Nile River <br>
    <input type="radio" value="c" name="question5">c) Amazon River<br>
    <input type="radio" value="d" name="question5">d) Yenisei River<br>
  </div>

  <p>
    <input type="button" id="init" value="Submit" />
  </p>

  <p id="results"></p>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have your `initialize()` function inside the `checkAll()` function. It should be a separate function.

Second, you never call `initialize()`.

Third, you use `$("#question1").val()` to get the value of a radio button, but `#` is for matching IDs, not names. The way to get the value of a radio button is `$(":radio[name=question1]:checked").val()` (see [jQuery get value of selected radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)).

Fourth, you return immediately whenever an answer is wrong. You need to keep going so you can report the total score.

Fifth, you need to initialize `score` to `0` in the function. Otherwise, you'll add the score for the current call to the score from the previous time. And `score` should just be a local variable in the function, there's no need for the global variable.

```js
//Question One Answer is 'a'
//Question One Answer is 'b'
//Question One Answer is 'b'
//Question One Answer is 'b'
//Question One Answer is 'a'


checkAll = function() {

  var message;
  var score = 0; 

  if ($(":radio[name=question1]:checked").val() === "a") {
    score++;
  }

  if ($(":radio[name=question2]:checked").val() === "b") {
    score++;
  }

  if ($(":radio[name=question3]:checked").val() === "b") {
    score++;
  }

  if ($(":radio[name=question4]:checked").val() === "b") {
    score++;
  }

  if ($(":radio[name=question5]:checked").val() === "a") {
    score++;
  }

  message = "You got " + score + " out of five questions right!";
  $("#results").html(message);

};

initialize = function() {
  $("#init").click(checkAll)
};

initialize();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<h1>Geography Quiz</h1>


<p>
  <label for="user">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="user" />
</p>
<div class="qheader">
  <p> 1) Which of the countries below is largest by area?</p>
</div>
<div class="questsel">
  <input type="radio" value="a" name="question1">a) Russia<br>
  <input type="radio" value="b" name="question1">b) China<br>
  <input type="radio" value="c" name="question1">c) USA<br>
  <input type="radio" value="d" name="question1">d) Canada<br>
</div>

<br>

<div class="qheader">
  <p> 2) Which of these cities is United States Capital?</p>
</div>
<div class="questsel">
  <input type="radio" value="a" name="question2">a) New York<br>
  <input type="radio" value="b" name="question2">b) Washington D.C
  <input type="radio" value="c" name="question2">c) Chicago<br>
  <input type="radio" value="d" name="question2">d) Moscow<br>
</div>

<div class="qheader">
  <p> 3) Which of these cities is Spain's Capital?</p>
</div>
<div class="questsel">
  <input type="radio" value="a" name="question3">a) Barcelona<br>
  <input type="radio" value="b" name="question3">b) Madrid <br>
  <input type="radio" value="c" name="question3">c) Milan<br>
  <input type="radio" value="d" name="question3">d) Rome<br>
</div>

<div class="qheader">
  <p> 4) Which ocean is the largest?</p>
</div>
<div class="questsel">
  <input type="radio" value="a" name="question4">a) Arctic<br>
  <input type="radio" value="b" name="question4">b) Pacific<br>
  <input type="radio" value="c" name="question4">c) Indian<br>
  <input type="radio" value="d" name="question4">d) Atlantic<br>
</div>

<div class="qheader">
  <p> 5) Which of these rivers is largest in North America?</p>
</div>
<div class="questsel">
  <input type="radio" value="a" name="question5">a) Missouri River<br>
  <input type="radio" value="b" name="question5">b) Nile River <br>
  <input type="radio" value="c" name="question5">c) Amazon River<br>
  <input type="radio" value="d" name="question5">d) Yenisei River<br>
</div>

<p>
  <input type="button" id="init" value="Submit" />
</p>

<p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: maybe `var score` should be removed as a global variable in this instance?

Comment: @barmar Thank you very much. I am just starting up and that awesome breakdown of issues and resolutions. It makes things click in my head due to your detailed explanation. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Barmar the snippet seems to work however when i run it in brackets it still doesn't work. attempted to first copy & paste but it didnt work so i retyped the code into brackets but still no luck.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "run it in brackets".