# Javascript OnChange event handler for radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a generalized solution for this.

Consider 4 radio type inputs with the same name. When submitted, the one that is checked determines the value that gets sent with the form:

I would like to have a text area displayed only at 1 and 3 :
its always working only with value 1 and never value 3.

Below is the code snippet.

```js
function getit() {
  var select = document.getElementById('f06_w01').checked;
  if (select == 1 || select == 3) {
    document.getElementById('whitch').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('whitch').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="f06_w01" name="f06_w01" value="1" onchange="getit();" required />
<input type="radio" id="f06_w01" name="f06_w01" value="2" onchange="getit();" required />
<input type="radio" id="f06_w01" name="f06_w01" value="3" onchange="getit();" required />
<input type="radio" id="f06_w01" name="f06_w01" value="4" onchange="getit();" required />

<div id="whitch" style="display: none;">
  <p><b>Whats better?</b></p>
  <p><textarea name="f06_t02" id="f06_t02" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
</div>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You can't use `id` for more than 1 element, `id`s must be unique. In this case, you are selecting just the first

Comment: Check below link if its useful for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button

Comment: You shouldn't use the same id for those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not selecting the checked input radio, you are just picking the first element with that id, since id *should* be unique.

You can fix it actually selecting the checked input radio:

```js
   function getit(){
        var select = document.querySelector('input[name="f06_w01"]:checked').value;
        if(select == 1 || select == 3) { document.getElementById('whitch').style.display = "block"; }
        else { 
            document.getElementById('whitch').style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="f06_w01" value="1" 
onchange="getit();" required />
<input type="radio" name="f06_w01" value="2" onchange="getit();" required />
<input type="radio" name="f06_w01" value="3" 
onchange="getit();" required />
<input type="radio" name="f06_w01" value="4" onchange="getit();" required />

<div id="whitch" style="display: none;">
<p><b>Whats better?</b></p>
<p><textarea name="f06_t02" id="f06_t02" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
</div>
```