# jQuery get correct value of selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

After research and lot of attempts of various implementations looking how to get radio button value from my application. Basically it is very simple radio button in file **Index.cshtml** :

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            <div style="padding: 0 20px;">
                <label for="star-filter2"> Projects vendors status:</label>
                <fieldset id="star-filter2">
                    <input class="radioCheck2" id="rated-filter2" value="true" type="radio" name="starfilter2" />Rated<img src="~/images/check.png" alt="tick box" height="20" width="20" />
                    <br />
                    <input class="radioCheck2" id="rated-filter2" value="false" type="radio" name="starfilter2" />Not rated<img src="~/images/excl_mark.png" alt="excl mark" height="20" width="20" />
                    <br />
                    <input class="radioCheck2" id="rated-filter2" value="null" type="radio" name="starfilter2" />NULL<img src="~/images/excl_mark.png" alt="excl mark" height="20" width="20" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my javascript code where I am trying to get selected radio button value:

```
    $("#filter2").click(function () {

    var showRated = $('#rated-filter2').is(':checked');
    localStorage.setItem("showRated", showRated);
    var location = $("#filter-button2").find("a").attr("href")....;
    window.location.href = location;
});
```

In this code line: var `showRated = $('#rated-filter2').is(':checked');` is working , but it is only to get value when it is checked. What I want , I want to get value of selected radio button, for example : true , "null" and any value which I insert into radio button.

I tried these lines, where I was getting 'undefined' or always false value.

```
$('#input[name=\'starfilter2\']:checked').val(); 
$('#rated-filter2:selected').val();
$('#input[name=starfilter2]:checked').val();
```

None of them it is not working.

Comment: You're using `#input` as the selector, but none of the elements have an ID of `input`. Try `$('input[name=starfilter2]:checked').val()`. Your three inputs also have the same ID, which shouldn't be the case - ID's should be unique to one element only on a page.

Comment: Since it's a radio, too, when the `change` event is fired, it means one of them is checked (you can't really un-check a radio button without code). So, without even checking if one is checked, you can just use something like this to get the checked radio's value: `$('[name=starfilter2]').change(function() { alert(this.value); });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of selected radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Comment: `$(":radio:checked").val();` `:radio` is a special jQuery selector equivalent to `$("input[type=radio]")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, first of all, there is no reason to have multiple Ids of the same name in this case rated-filter2. IDs are supposed to be unique (like a driver's license ID or a social security number)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
        var radioValue = $("input[name='star-filter2']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue){
            alert("Selected: " + radioValue);
        }
    });
});
```

Or replace this

```
var radioValue = $("input[name='star-filter2']:checked").val();
```

with this

```
var radioValue = $("input[id='rated-filter2']:checked").val();
```

Keep in mind to have unique IDs.

Comment: Just to follow-up regarding names for radios - if you have a radio group, all radio inputs in the group should have the same name (that's how they're tied together so only one radio can be checked in the same-named group). If the names are different, the radios won't be tied together, they'll just basically be rounded checkboxes that can't be unchecked. https://jsfiddle.net/rwejadho/