# Radio button with different ids, different values, same name attribute

Tags: javascript, php, radio-button

I got my radio Selector that looks like this

```
<div id="graph_selector" style="display:none; text-align: center;" >
   <p><b>Tipo de Grafico: </b></p>
     <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="axes" type="radio" name="sel_graph" class="radio_selector" value="axes" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc axes"for="axes"></label>
        <input id="activity" type="radio" name="sel_graph" class="radio_selector" value="activity" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc activity" for="activity"></label>
        <input id="pie" type="radio" name="sel_graph" class="radio_selector" value="pie" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc pie" for="pie"></label>
     </div>
</div>
```

A button to submit my selection

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="guardar_grafico">Graficar</button>
```

Im trying to get the right value on my js but when I use console.log(); all I get is the value from the 1st input= "axes" regardless of what I choose

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$('#guardar_grafico').click(function() {
       var graph_selector = document.querySelector('input[name=sel_graph]').value
       console.log(graph_selector);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm, solved the issue, I was missing the checked property on my js

it went from this

```
var graph_selector = document.querySelector('input[name=sel_graph]').value
```

to this

```
var graph_selector = document.querySelector('input[name=sel_graph]:checked').value
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of the selected radio in a radio group, you need to look for the `checked` property on each radio.

In this example, it loops through all of the radios with that `name="sel_graph"` attribute, and filters that list to the 1 radio that is checked.

```js
var graph_selector = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name=sel_graph]')
).filter(radio => radio.checked)[0]?.value;
console.log(graph_selector);
```

Also, I just realized you're using jQuery. There's a simpler solution with that, check this answer.

[jQuery get value of selected radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)