# How to check radio button in jquery new version 1.7.1?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, attributes, jquery-1.7

```
<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-divider-theme='b'>
    <li data-role='list-divider'>
        <label>Radio Button</label>
    </li>
    <li data-theme='c'>
        <fieldset data-role='controlgroup'>
            <input id='radio1' type='radio' name='Delete' />
            <label for='radio1'>Radio 1</label>
            <input id='radio2' type='radio' name='Delete' />
            <label for='radio2'>Radio 2</label>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
</ul>
<div data-role='navbar'>
    <ul data-inset='true'>
        <li><a data-role='button' href='#' id='delete' data-icon='check'>Ok</a></li>
        <li><a data-role='button' href='#' id='Cancel' data-icon='delete'>Cancel</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
var radTrn = $("#radio1").attr('checked');//here it is coming as undefined
var radRstAl = $("#radio2").attr('checked');//here it is coming as undefined
```

i m using jquery mobile simple dialog box RAW HTML mode.The radio button checking was working in jquery 1.6.4 and in 1.7.1 it was not working

Comment: What does not work?  Because you never actually stated what you're really trying to do here.   Are you trying to programatically select the radio button, are you trying to test its current state, or something else?  Please also post your relevant HTML code.

Comment: now i m given relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#check').prop('checked');
```

Then checkout http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I assumed this may be the issue, though I think `attr()` should still work for this, even in 1.7.1. I mean, i don't see a reason for it not to (unless I've missed something in the docs).

Comment: The syntax error aside your code should "work". However, it will  return the string "checked" instead of boolean true. Is your logic checking for a string value instead of a boolean?

Comment: i m using this $('#check').prop('checked');  if i check the radio button then also it is giving false

Comment: could you perhaps past the code you're using to render your radio button? @Joe's code is correct, but it's possible that the selector we're using is missing the point.

Comment: +1, Definitely get in the habit of using `prop` in place of `attr`, but the root cause of the original problem is still a mystery.  OP, please post more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#check').attr('checked');
```

problem with quotes..i dont see any other compability issue..

You also try  `$('#check').is(':checked')`

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/c1e230f650a27d26142ba52a42dfa1940e85a46c  see this this issue only i was getting now they solved thanks for all your replies

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a simple formatting issue (you've got an extra quote in there), I'd guess that the `checked` attribute doesn't have a value assigned. That's still valid HTML, but it may throw a wrench in jQuery's cogs.

Fortunately, there's a fairly easy workaround for your test. Just use the `:checked` pseudo-class as follows:

```
var isChecked = $('#check').is(':checked');
```

This will return a boolean (`true` if it is checked and `false` if not), so you can use this as an operator.

Comment: by mistakely i added that quote there.

Comment: $('#check').is(':checked'); like that i was using but if i check the radio button then also it is coming as false.

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery

Comment: for this $('#check').is(':checked'); also after checking 
it is giving as false

Comment: Wait a second... are we testing for current state or setting it programatically?