# Check which radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

----EDIT----

I am making an jquery mobile application. Now I want to check which radiobutton is checked.

This is what I do in my javascript.

```
function filter(){
    if(document.getElementById('segment1').checked) {
         alert('Iedereen');
    }else if(document.getElementById('segment2').checked) {
         alert('team');
    }else{
        alert('favorieten');
    }
}
```

En this is my HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" onchange=filter() > 
    <input type="radio" name="radio-view"  data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly"  id="segment1" value="choice1" checked="checked"/> 
    <label for="segment1"  id="controls">
    <span class="ui-btn-text-controls">Iedereen</span>
    </label> 
    <input type="radio" name="radio-view" data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly" id="segment2" value="choice2" /> 
    <label for="segment2" id="controls">
    <span class="ui-btn-text-controls">Team</span>
    </label> 
    <input type="radio" name="radio-view" data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly" id="segment3" value="choice3" /> 
    <label for="segment3" id="controls">
    <span class="ui-btn-text-controls">Favorieten</span>
    </label>  
</fieldset>
```

For some reason it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

kind regards.

Comment: Where you're firing  this js code

Comment: call this on check change or some button click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery

Comment: Yes that was more my question, it should do this code when you select a radiobutton. Should you do this with a onClick-event ?

Comment: @user1251632: fire it onchange of the fieldset

Comment: I've edited my question with the code I have right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example working http://jsfiddle.net/Jgrgk/4/

Answer (score 1):

```
function AlertRadioId( groupName ) { //groupName is "radio-view"
    var radios = document.getElementsByName( groupName );
    for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {
        if( radios[i].checked ) {
            alert(radios[i].value);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

need to call this function in a event of button / radio button onclick event