# Get the current radio element index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i'm iterating a collection of inputs, how can I get the current radio index if the input is part of a group of radios?

```
$('input').each(function(){

  if($(this).is(':radio')){
    // here get the index of the radio in the radio group,
    // like 1, 2, 3 etc... 
  }


});
```

The index should be relative to the radio group, no the entire collection of input elements.

The group is determined by the input name (inputs having the same name).

Comment: post some html that we can work with

Comment: Wouldn't `$('input:radio').each` be better than `$('input').each`?

Comment: @j08691 Only if you're only interested in radio inputs in the iteration, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the position of the `radio` within the group defined by the `radio`'s `name` attribute:

```
$('input:radio').each(
    function(){
        console.log($(this).index('[name="' + this.name + '"]'));
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gNgBx/1/).

References:

- [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`:radio` selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input:radio').each(function(el, i){
    //i is your index
});
```

Update:  I found this as well for finding the selected value of a radio group.  [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: +1, better answer than mine. You learn something new every day :-)

Comment: I'm not positive this actually answers the question.

Comment: @LiorCohen It's definitely valid syntax, but it doesn't take into affect grouping of radio elements, which is what the question asks for.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: gotcha. Well, no HTML means this answer would have to be a bit generic. A good point nevertheless.

Comment: @LiorCohen I'd say there's a world of difference between "a bit generic" and "doesn't answer the question at all". The question is answerable without HTML, just see David Thomas's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = $('input');

inputs.each(function()
{
  if ($(this).is(':radio')) {
    console.log(inputs.index(this));
  }
});
```