# Setting Django Form html id

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

I've modified the django comment form and noticed that it does not output with an html id.  How can I add an html id to the entire form?

I need the id so I can get the value of a radio select in jQuery.

**EDIT:**
I've tried Matthew Schinckel's method below:

```
var output = $("input[name=rating]:checked").val();
$('#some_div').text(output).fadeIn(500);
```

This returns nothing.

Comment: Why do you need an id on the form? Also, you generally have to write the `<form>` tags yourself in django.

Comment: I'd like to get the value of a radio select with jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery

Comment: If the name of the tag is unique in the page, just use `$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val()`.

Comment: You don't need the form to have an id for that. This is rather an HTML/Javascript question than a Django question as far as I understand it. Could you post the HTML and tell radio you want ? Thanks in advance for putting some effort in your topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does put the id of every form element in. You may be able to just use this in jQuery. Or, as okm suggested, use the `name` attribute.

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val()
```

Or, using django's default naming:

```
$('#id_radioName').val()
```

(The id may differ if you have multiple forms/formsets on your page).

Comment: I had trouble with this originally, but realized I was removing the form with jQuery before getting the radiobutton value.  Thx