# get selected value of radio button onclick of submit and pass value to a function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am doing some work in PHP. I have two php page

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll-vote.php?vote="+int,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Is this correct? </h3>
<div id="poll">

<form>
Yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0">
<br>No:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Forward" onclick="getVote(value);"> 
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

on click of submit button I need to get the value of selected radio button and pass it to the function.

Please help me

Comment: Do you use a library like jQuery or plain js ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery

Comment: @mallix - Here I am not using any library

Answer (score 1):

call just a function in youe onclick inline...

```
 <input type="submit" value="Forward" onclick="getVote();"> //here
```

and get checked radio value in your function..

```
var radiovalue= $('input[name="vote"]:checked').val()
```

try this

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function getVote()
{
 var radiovalue= $('input[name="vote"]:checked').val()
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{

 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll-vote.php?vote="+radiovalue,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Forward" onclick="getVote();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide action and method attribute to form first

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

And than only you can get the value like below:

```
$vote = $_POST['vote'];
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: he's doing a AJAX call, sooo nope.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function getVote()
{
    var int=document.getElementById("vote").value;
    ....
```

EDIT: noticed it is a radio input... so this won't work. You need something like:

```
function getRadioCheckedValue(radio_name)
{
   var oRadio = document.forms[0].elements[radio_name];

   for(var i = 0; i < oRadio.length; i++)
   {
      if(oRadio[i].checked)
      {
         return oRadio[i].value;
      }
   }

   return '';
}
```

And then do:

```
function getVote()
{
    var int=getRadioCheckedValue(vote);
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Via jquery you can get value of selected radio like this:

```
$('input[name=vote]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing those 2:

```
<form name="myForm"> 

onclick="getValue(document.myForm);"
```

then the function:

```
function getValue(form){
 var value = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
   if (form.elements[i].type == 'radio') {
         if(form.elements[i].checked == true) {
             value = form.elements[i].value;
        }
     }
   }

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll-vote.php?vote="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function without any value and then read out the radiobutton inbetween your function like this:

```
var rval = document.getElementsByName('vote');

for (var i = 0, length = rval.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (rval[i].checked) {
        alert(rval[i].value); // your value
    }
}
```