# Radio Button "Checked=checked" not changing when option changed

Tags: html, css, forms, input, checked

I've created a basic 2 radio button form as seen in my example below.

Observing the browser rendering, we see item 1 selected. We inspect item 1 and 2.

When I click item 2, I expect item 1's checked=checked to be remove. I expect item 2 receive the attribute checked=checked.

Is this not the expected behavior?

```
<div>
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" checked="checked" />
</div>

<div>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" class="checkbox" id="radio2" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrimbus/ZTE7R/1/

Comment: @quentin and others: Your replies are great, does this confirm then that the expected behavior of an _attribute_ "checked" will not automatically update **without the use of Javascript?**

Comment: I was able to style the "checked" radio button and label by applying styles using a pseudo selector :checked. This works for IE9+, Chrome and Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/sXjyL/4/

Comment: A more clear answer as to how to work with radio buttons using jQuery is on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery

Answer (score 24):

The `checked` *attribute* specifies the *default* checked radio button, not the currently checked one.

See this example code:

```js
function setChecked() {
  document.getElementById('x1').removeAttribute('checked');
  document.getElementById('x2').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
}

document.querySelector('[type=button]').addEventListener('click', setChecked);
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="x" type="radio" id="x1" checked>
  <input name="x" type="radio" id="x2">
  <button type="button">Switch</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Click the second radio button, then click Reset. Then click the second radio button again, then Switch, then Reset.

The checked *property* will give the *current* checked state of a radio button.

[image: Checked attribute vs checked property]

Comment: Was waiting for that *property* vs *attribute* distinction :)

Comment: @quentin Your replies are great, does this confirm then that the expected behavior of an attribute "checked" will not automatically update without the use of Javascript?

Comment: Yes. Only JavaScript can change the checked *attribute* once the page has loaded.