# Load text file content using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a `HTML` and `CSS` tab where i want to load the text content under each tab using `ajax` request from a `.txt` file. It means when we click on any tab then it loads the text content from `.txt` file. Content will be loaded first time a tabs get activated. First tab is already activated and text content loaded and showing under first tab but my issue is but when i click on second or third tab then it doesn't load the text content. 
Code is live here: http://testweb.epizy.com/ajax-load/index.html

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I have given a live url. you can check that.

Answer (score 2):

If you set IDs of the radio buttons the same as file names, i.e. tab1, tab2 and tab3, the result JavaScript code can look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const SELECTOR = '[type=radio]';

  function loadData(tabId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: `${tabId}.txt`,
      dataType: "text",
      async: false,
      success: (data) => {
        $(`.${tabId}`).html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  const checkedTabId = $(`${SELECTOR}:checked`).prop('id');
  loadData(checkedTabId);

  $(SELECTOR).change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      loadData(this.id);
    }
  });
});
```

It's just a brief example of how your code could be improved.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2zoatjj2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [JQuery load function](https://api.jquery.com/load/) . Since you haven't supplied any code, I'm unable to help you better.

Here is your code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($("#one").is(":checked")){
          $.ajax({
              url : "tab1.txt",
              dataType: "text",
              async:false,
              success : function (data) {
                  $(".tab1").html(data);
              }
          });
      };
      if ($("#two").is(":checked")){
          $.ajax({
              url : "tab2.txt",
              dataType: "text",
              async:false,
              success : function (data) {
                  $(".tab2").html(data);
              }
          });
      };
      if ($("#three").is(":checked")){
          $.ajax({
              url : "tab3.txt",
              dataType: "text",
              async:false,
              success : function (data) {
                  $(".tab3").html(data);
              }
          });
      };
    });
```

You should do it like this, add:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function loadText(){
      if ($("#one").is(":checked")){
           $.ajax({
             url : "tab1.txt",
             dataType: "text",
             async:false,
             success : function (data) {
               $(".tab1").html(data);
            }
         });
       }
       if ($("#two").is(":checked")){
          $.ajax({
            url : "tab2.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            async:false,
            success : function (data) {
              $(".tab2").html(data);
            }
         });
      }
      if ($("#three").is(":checked")){
          $.ajax({
          url : "tab3.txt",
          dataType: "text",
          async:false,
          success : function (data) {
              $(".tab3").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    }
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(loadText);
  });
```

Comment: I didn't want to shorten your code and waste my time :) so here is solution using your code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your source code, I see that your JavaScript is supposed to run when the "checked" attribute of buttons 2 and 3 is set, but the checked attribute is meant for the default option in a radio selection--not for the currently selected option. When you change the tab the first button will still have the checked attribute because it is always the default. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836320/radio-button-checked-checked-not-changing-when-option-changed) for some more info on that.

I'd change your javascript to something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($("#one").is(":checked")){
            $.ajax({
                url : "tab1.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                async:false,
                success : function (data) {
                    $(".tab1").html(data);
                }
            });
        };
    });
    function loadOne() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "tab1.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            async:false,
            success : function (data) {
                $(".tab1").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    function loadTwo() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "tab2.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            async:false,
            success : function (data) {
                $(".tab2").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    function loadThree() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "tab3.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            async:false,
            success : function (data) {
                $(".tab3").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And then adding an onclick event to the three buttons (not positive if this would go on the `<input>` or the `<label>`), so add `onclick=loadOne()` for the first button, loadTwo() for the second, and loadThree() for the third.

My code is probably a little redundant, I'm a bit of a beginner, but hopefully this helps.