# run SQL query based on radio box checked

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have this PHP code that is displaying multiple radio buttons:

```
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION["resellers"] as $reseller) {
    $sql2="SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '".$reseller."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
    echo '<input type="radio" name="reseller" value="'.$reseller.'" /> '.$result2["company"].'<br>';
}
?>
```

i want to run another SQL query a little lower down the page based on the checked radio button:

```
<select name="reseller_customer">
<option value="">Please Choose</option>
<?php
$sql2="SELECT * from customer where resellerid = '".$reseller."' ";
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
echo '<option value="'.$reseller.'">'.$result2["company"].'</option>';
?>
</select>
```

how can i do the `where resellerid = "CHECKED RADIO BUTTON"`

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use some ajax call or something, since php has already been executed when the user selected the radio button.

To get the selected radio button you can use jquery:

```
<script>
    var id = $("#myform input[type='radio']:checked").val();
</sciprt>
```

Then, you can send an ajax request with $id to execute the desired sql.

You can also check this: [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

And the ajax request should look like:

```
function myAjaxRequest(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://path/to/file/with/the/sql/function',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (response) {
            alert ("Everything went fine!)";
        }
    });
}
```

In the file with the Sql function, you can get the selected id with:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
```

Comment: this isn't setting the PHP value $id to the value of the selected radio button

Comment: I changed to be $id = $("#myform input[name='reseller']:checked").val();

Comment: This is javascript, so it should be var id = ... I edited the answer. But still you are not done. You should pass this value to the ajax request.

Comment: how do i pass it to an ajax request?

Comment: i don't want to have to refresh the page, is this possible?

Comment: With ajax you do not refresh it.

Comment: do i need to add an on click event or anything?

Comment: ok, within the foreach loop i have added onClick="myAjaxRequest('.$reseller.')" onto the radio button. the popup box shows saying everything went fine but when i echo $_POST["id"] it shows nothing

Comment: You need a new php file that contains the sql query among with any other piece of code that you need to execute. So, $_POST["id"] works on this new file. If you want to print it somewhere in the main page, in the new file add return($id); and then instead of the alert add print response;

Comment: NO! in this case the page should be refreshed, which you didn't want. You put the code in a different file and you call the code with the ajax request. You get the response and you print it with javascript without the need of refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Since "CHECKED RADIO BUTTON" is not value itself, the same query you previously did should do what you need. When a radio button is checked, only the value of the checked radio button is passed to the database.

Comment: its the value of the "reseller" radio buttons within the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[name='reseller']").change(function() {
                var resellerid = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "company.php",
                    data: {resellerid: resellerid}
                })
                        .done(function(company) {
                            $("select[name='reseller_customer'] option[value='']").next().remove();
                            $("select[name='reseller_customer']").append("<option value='" + resellerid + "'>" + company + "</option>");
                        });
            });
        });
    </script>
```