# jQuery radio button if statement

Tags: jquery, radio-button

How can I do a simple if statement based on radio button selection?

So if radio button inches is displayed, then div.inchesUser is shown (using .show)
And the opposite for centimetres.

This is what I want the function to do:

```
$('div.inchesUser').show(200);
```

This is my radio button code:

```
<form id="unitChooser">
    <label>Inches or centimetres?</label>
    <input class="unitSelectInches" type="radio" name="units" value="inches" />Inches
    <input class="unitSelectCenti" checked="checked" type="radio" name="units" value="cms" />Centimetres
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("input:radio[name=units]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 'inches')
        $('div.centimetreUser').show(200);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8pEp2/8/)

Comment: You shouldn't have the whole thing in an `if`.

Comment: check this jsfiddle I have make an update: http://jsfiddle.net/8pEp2/8/ @Francesca

Comment: It does work however if you check the other radio button afterwards then the other form appears. How do I hide the old form if you choose the other button? http://jsfiddle.net/8pEp2/11/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
<form id="unitChooser">
    <label>Inches or centimetres?</label>
    <input class="unitSelectInches" data-class='inchesUser' type="radio" name="units" value="inches" />Inches
    <input class="unitSelectCenti" data-class='centimetresUser' checked="checked" type="radio" name="units" value="cms" />Centimetres
</form>

$('input:radio[name=units]').on('change', function () {
    $('div.centimetreUser, div.inchesUser').hide();
    $('div.' + $(this).data('class')).show(200);
});
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/WT2uc/

Comment: @Francesca See this demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/WT2uc/ ------ your fiddle updated `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/8pEp2/12/