# How can I send radio button value in PHP using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been at this for week and read all the stackoverflow and google and I can not fix this problem.
Every time I test it I get the first radio button no matter which one I click.

What i get in the email is:

```
Name: test
Email: test@live.com
phone: 9545027557
type: Residential
```

**HTML:**

```html
<form name="controls" id="controls"  novalidate>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Full Name" id="name" required
                   data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" 
                   id="email" required
                   data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="optionu" style="padding-left:25px"> 
                <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="optionu" name="optionu"
                           value="Residential" checked > Residential 
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary ">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="optionu" name="optionu"
                           value="Commercial" > Commercial
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary ">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="optionu" name="optionu"
                           value="Handyman" > Handyman
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>

    <div id="success"> </div> <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Request</button><br />
</form>
```

**contact_me.js:**

```js
var name = $("input#name").val();  
var email = $("input#email").val(); 
var phone = $("input#phone").val(); 
var optionu = $("input#optionu").val();
var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
// Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
    firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
}        
$.ajax({
    url: "bin/contact_me.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: name, email: email,  optionu: optionu,  phone: phone},
    cache: false,
    success: function() {  
        // Success message
        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
        $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append( "</button>");
        $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
        $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');
```

**contact_me.php:**

```php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$optionu_value = $_POST['optionu'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];

// create email body and send it
$to = 'test@gmail.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
              " Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n  ".
              "Email: $email_address\n phone: $phone\n  type: $optionu";
```

Comment: Too much code, is it really all relevant to the question?

Comment: I think i get it...the input radio have to be named the same, but, just delete the id on those radio...you can retrieve the selected value..i'm gonna post a test answer...

Comment: sry about this tried to give all the info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you use same id 4 times. [ID have to be unique in document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id), you cannot set same id to 4 elements. Also I think the way you are getting value from radio button is wrong.

This is more or less how you can get value from radio button: ( [example](http://jsfiddle.net/scx/9qSYa/) from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery) )

```
  var optionu = $('input[name=optionu]:checked', '#controls').val()
```

Also remove id from all input[radio] elements.

```
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
   <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="optionu" value="Residential" checked /> Residential 
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary ">
   <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="optionu" value="Commercial" /> Commercial
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-primary ">
   <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="optionu" value="Handyman" /> Handyman
 </label>
```

Comment: thanks i know id but it was the only thing working but thanks again i can not tell you how much this helped me

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the checked value of the radio.  You're just getting the value of the first radio element.

[How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Edit: You also can't use the same ID for every radio button.  You'll have to give it a class name or refer to the button by name with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name=optionu]:checked').val()
```

#### Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9dYrR/