# How to capture selected radio Button Value?

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery

This is my HTML Section

```
<input type="radio" id="admin" value="admin"/>Admin<br>
<input type="radio" id="superadmin" value="superadmin"/>Super Admin<br>


$(document).ready(function() {
    var selecctedtype = '';
    if (document.getElementById('admin').checked) {
        selecctedtype = 'admin';
    }
    if (document.getElementById('superadmin').checked) {
        selecctedtype = 'superadmin';
    }
    alert(selecctedtype);
});
```

But i am getting empty alert

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kua4tfhd/1/

Could anybody please let me know how to capture it ??

Comment: It's empty because nothing is selected.

Comment: it's normal since none of your radio button is checked when the page is loaded

Comment: You need to have a common name for both the radios elements first then `$('input[name="somename"]:checked').val()`... also need to use a change handler

Comment: @ArunPJohny , i have tried as mentioned this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kua4tfhd/7/ but its not working . On click of a submit button i wanted this value .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kua4tfhd/9/

Answer (score 2):

Alert is empty because nothing is selected at the moment the script is executed.

**1).** If you want your radio buttons to act like radio buttons you must give them the same name:

```
<input type="radio" name="role" id="admin" value="admin" /> Admin
<input type="radio" name="role" id="superadmin" value="superadmin" /> Super Admin
```

**2).** Then you would bind `onchange` event to detect when user changes selection. To select radio buttons you can use for example specific name selector or/and `:radio` input selector:

```
$(':radio[name=role]').change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

**3).** Later when you want to get selected value you can do something like this using `:checked` selector:

```
var role = $(':radio[name=role]:checked').val();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kua4tfhd/10/

Comment: Your solution is the only one where the radio button functionality actually works (if one is selected the other is deselected). +1

Answer (score 1):

you have to handle it in click event:

### HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="admin" class="role" value="admin" />Admin
<br>
<input type="radio" id="superadmin" class="role" value="superadmin" />Super Admin
<br>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".role").click(function () {

        alert($(this).val())
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but  On click of a submit button i wanted this value .

Comment: use this @Kiran : ``alert($(".role[checked='checked']").val());`` or ``alert($(".role:checked").val());``

Comment: or you can also use: ``alert($("input:radio:checked").val());``

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val();
```

[Reference..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)