# Selected checkbox adds 35% to total price?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, percentage

This is a form using jQuery to calculate price.
I would need it to add 35% to Total Price when the checkbox input #percent is selected.
Here is my code:

```
<h1>Starting value:<br/>3</h1>

<p>
Multiply by:<br>
    <select id="multiply">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>
</p>

<p>
Substract:<br>
    <input type="number" id="substract" value="0" min="0" />
</p>

<p>
+ 35% when selected (how??): 
     <input type="checkbox" id="percent" />
</p>
<hr>
<p id="totaltext">Total Price: 
     <div id="totalprice"></div> $
</p>


<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function calculate(){
        var multiply = $('#multiply').val();
        var substract = $('#substract').val();
        var percent = $('#percent').val();

        var totalprice = 3 * multiply - substract;

        $('#totalprice').html(totalprice.toFixed(2));

    }



    $(function() {
        $('#multiply').change(function(){
            calculate();

        });
    });


        $(function() {
                $('#substract').change(function(){
            calculate();

        });
    });



        $(function() {
                $('#percent').change(function(){
            calculate();

        });
    });

})  
</script>
```

Also, I would like the Total (#totalprice) to never go lower than 0.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Homework problem?  Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. What do you mean by write `calculate`?

Comment: @EdHeal - It seems a bit harsh in this case. OP needed a couple of lines changed / added. He / she didn't just dump a question with no / useless code.

Comment: My mistake - Missed the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try code :

```
function calculate(){
    var multiply = $('#multiply').val();
    var substract = $('#substract').val();
    var percent = $("#percent").is(':checked');

    var totalprice = 3 * multiply - substract;
    if (percent) totalprice = totalprice*0.35;
    $('#totalprice').html(totalprice.toFixed(2));

}
```

Code example is [here](http://jsbin.com/sacara/3/edit?html,output)

I edited for check total price > 0. You can see code [here](http://jsbin.com/sacara/11/edit?html,output)

Comment: You should not answer others homework

Comment: Lol. This is no homework. Thanks for guiding me ryan, I got it working using your code with `totalprice+(totalprice*0.35);` (to add percentage to total)!

Comment: Now is there a quick way to prevent #pricetotal from going into the negative values?

Comment: Nice thanks for the 1.35 tip

Comment: I edited for check total price > 0. You can see code [here](http://jsbin.com/sacara/11/edit?html,output)