# jQuery - get active button from buttons group (input type = "radio")

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap buttons, which look like regular buttons but they act like radio.

```
<div class="btn-group-horizontal" data-toggle="buttons" id ="Group">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-info btnSelect active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="Option 1" autocomplete="off" checked> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-info btnSelect">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="Option 2" autocomplete="off"> Option 2
  </label>
</div>
```

How can I get the ID / text of the active button?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was the following:

I had to change the HTML by addiong ID to the lable

```
<div class="btn-group-horizontal" data-toggle="buttons" id ="Group">
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-info btnSelect active" **id="Option 1"**>
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="Option 1" autocomplete="off" checked> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-info btnSelect" **id="Option 2"**>
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="Option 2" autocomplete="off"> Option 2
  </label>
</div>
```

and by using following jQuery:

```
var answer= '';
            $('#Group .active').each(function(){
                answer= $(this).attr('id'); 
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just use a simple CSS selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($('.active input').prop('id'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/L7maoufy/

Comment: this should be flag as the response

Answer (score 1):

Can try using `each()` & `is()`. Example:

```
var activeId = '';
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        activeId = $(this).attr('id'); 
        //alert(activeId);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I limit this to specific group of buttons only ( in this case id = "Group"?

Comment: you can use `$('input[name="options"]').each(...)` ;

Comment: @Vika then can use `$('#Group input[type=radio]').each()` instead