# Jquery radio button selector not working

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to get all the checked radio buttons under a div element. But its not working. I think I am doing something wrong.

```
#divElement input[type="radio"]:checked
```

Comment: please share your html code also

Comment: Isn't the purpose of a radio button, you select only one?

Comment: Yes Steven, I have multiple radio buttons, just want to know which one is selected. But it is a common code want to work for checkbox also

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: Look at this example (the same selector but used with css): http://jsfiddle.net/qvm6qz04/

Comment: This question is not very clear. What do you want to achieve? Your selector appears ok to me for what you ask. I guess you want to do something after selecting them, but that is not stated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` property will give you selected radio button value.

```
$('#divElement input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/3441/)**

Comment: @void Check my demo and give me reason why wrong selector?

Comment: Yes now it is right, Eariler their was `"` mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#divElement input').on('change', function() {
       alert($('input[type=radio]:checked', '#divElement ').val()); 
    });
```

this way you can get the value of selected radio.Also your question is not clear whether it wants list of selected radios or just one?