# Having Issue On Setting Default Selected & Getting Selected Value On Bootstrap 3 Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this Bootstrap 3 Radio button example](http://www.bootply.com/fH82yZdBK4) and let me know why I am not able to set default selected radio for second option?

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> opt 1 
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> opt 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> opt 3
  </label>
</div>
```

as you can see I have already set the second option as:

```
 <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> opt 2
```

but the `checked="checked"` is not doing the job!
Can you please also let me know how I can get selected radio value by jquery
?

Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style the second option as the default just add the `active` class to the label (and remove it from the first one).

To learn how to get the selected value using jQuery look at [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery).