# Is using THIS more efficent than using the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form so user send his vote. 
There I need to know what radio button user select.
The version I found to solve it was this. [How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

```
value = $('input[name=vote]:checked', '#frmSurvey').val();
```

This work ok. Even when I dont understand how that work, because in [Jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) selector documentation there is only 2 example with item separated by coma. And neither match my example where each element is inside a quote and then a coma

> .class , .class    ---> $(".intro,.demo")  All elements with the class "intro" or "demo"
>   el1 , el2 , el3    ---> $("h1,div,p")  All < h1>, < div> and < p> elements

Both looks like OR selector instead of find A **and** then find B inside A.

> So if anyone can tell me what kind of selector is that I would love to take a look into the documentation

Now the optimization I was thinking. If I already inside a function for `#frmSurvey` won't be  faster if I use the `this` element

```
 $('#frmSurvey').ajaxForm(function () {                                
            value = $('input[name=vote]:checked', '#frmSurvey').val();
            console.log('working way ' + value);

            value = $(this).find('input[name=vote]:checked').val();
            console.log('testing way ' + value);
```

But I couldn't make the second version to work. Second value get me undefined.

So how I fix second version?

And would be second version better than first one as my instinct suggest or I'm worrying too much?

Comment: `$('input[name=vote]:checked', '#frmSurvey')` is not a single selector. It's http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context instead. *"Second value get me undefined."* Maybe `this` doesn't refer to `#frmSurvey` then?

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, as Klors mention `ajaxForm` create a diferent context. If I create `$('#frmSurvey').click(function ()` there my `$(this)` verson works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example shows a selector operating from a [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), whereas the documentation you've shown shows a ["multiple selectors"](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) selector.

You seem to have partially grasped this as

`value = $('input[name=vote]:checked', '#frmSurvey').val();`

is essentially the same as

`value = $('#frmSurvey').find('input[name=vote]:checked').val();`

However, the context of "this" inside your function is not clear as it depends upon how the `ajaxForm` plugin is coded. It isn't necessarily the result of your initial selector. After a short play with the plugin, it would appear that `this` in the context of `ajaxForm` is the jQuery ajax request object.

Comment: Thanks for the context selector, didnt know that part.  I did one more test, try creating `$('#frmSurvey').click(function ()` and there my `$(this)` version works. So as you say ajaxForm create a different context as the one i was expecting.

Comment: In other note I just pass the 200 point barrier thanks to this question. So happy :).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no problem and congratulations! I had a quick look at the plugin and it looks like `this` would be the jQuery ajax xhr object.