# Get all related value of checked item place in table

Tags: jquery

I want to know how can I get all values related to a checkbox using jquery.
From this picture , when a checkbox is checked all the values related to the checkbox can added to a array or alerted to user.
The code of the table is as follows

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" name="chkAll"></th>
         <th>From</th>
         <th>Request</th>
         <th>Expires on</th>
         <th>Post Date</th>
         <th>Location</th>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="showtable">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><input type="checkbox" value="fridge" id="1" name="request[]" class="request"> </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b><a href="user/">user1</a></b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>fridge</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>12-01-2015</b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>11/6/2014 2:25 pm</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><input type="checkbox" value="pizza" id="6" name="request[]" class="request"> </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b><a href="user/">user2</a></b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>pizza</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>12-01-2015</b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>11/7/2014 4:31 pm</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b></b></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do this?If you need any other resource please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get which radio is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: No.This is not duplicate of this post.The post solved issue to get value of selected radio button.But in my question when you click any checkbox then show all the related data of the checkbox.For example if you check the 1st checkbox then the array of result sholud contain user1,fridge,12-01-2015,11/6/2014 2:25 pm.
If you click maultiple checkbox then then it would store all the value in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the below code which solved this issue for me:

```
$('#send_kaving').click(function() {
                    arr=Array();
                    arrNew=[];
                    //arrNew[k]=Array();
                    jQuery('#showtable input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                        var v=jQuery(this).val();
                        arr.push(v);
                    });
                    jQuery.each(arr,function(ke,v){
                        var k=ke;
                        arrNew[k]=[];
                        jQuery("#showRequest"+v).find("td").each(function(key,val){
                            // alert(k);
                            var x=jQuery(this).text();
                            arrNew[k].push(x);
                        });
                    });
                    alert(arrNew);

                });
```

First get all the value of the checked items from the table and stored it in an array.Then from the array value I got the related value of the checkbox of the table row.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery `val()` method.

```
 $('.request').change(function(){
   alert(this.value); //using DOMelement value proprty
   or
   alert($(this).val());
 });
```

to get all the checked values and pass it into array you can use `.map`

```js
$('.request').change(function(){
       var checkedvalues = $('.request:checked').map(function(){
          return this.value
        }).get()
       console.log(checkedvalues);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" name="chkAll"></th>
         <th>From</th>
         <th>Request</th>
         <th>Expires on</th>
         <th>Post Date</th>
         <th>Location</th>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="showtable">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><input type="checkbox" value="fridge" id="1" name="request[]" class="request"> </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b><a href="user/">user1</a></b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>fridge</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>12-01-2015</b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>11/6/2014 2:25 pm</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><input type="checkbox" value="pizza" id="6" name="request[]" class="request"> </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b><a href="user/">user2</a></b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>pizza</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>12-01-2015</b></td><td style="border:1px solid black;"><b>11/7/2014 4:31 pm</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><b></b></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Check you console for checkedvalues

Comment: Not like that.This showing the value of the selected item .I want to show all the related data.For e.g, if you select 1st check box the result should contain    user1,fridge,12-01-2015,11/6/2014 2:25 pm

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values of checked checkboxes in an array, you can use the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) in conjunction with [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var values = $('#showtable input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get();
alert(values);
```

This can be called in any place you want

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];
//Filter out the check all th - Also assumes that this table is the only table on the page. If it is not then give the table an id
var $th = $('th:gt(0)');
$('#showtable input:checkbox').on('change',function(){
    var userInfo = {};


    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(i){
        //You can add the values to array here
        userInfo["'" + $th.eq(i).text().trim() + "'"] = $(this).text().trim();
    });
    //You might want to delete the old data in the array(if exists) before you add the new one 
    array.push(userInfo); 
});
```

Comment: Yes.This solved my problem partially.the array is now like this.   array(1=>user1,2=>fridge,3=>12-01-2015,4=>11/6/2014 2:25 pm).
But how can I get one checkbox data to array 1 st element like, 
array(1=>user1,fridge,12-01-2015,11/6/2014 2:25 pm,2=>user2,computer,12-01-2015,11/6/2014 2:25 pm) like that.