# Get group radio button selected value via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, radio-button

How can I get the selected radio button value via jQuery? I tried:

```
var selectedPlan = $("input[name=Plan[packageId]]:checked'").val();
alert(selectedPlan);
```

bBt didn't work.

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="Plan[packageId]">
    <lable>3 Games</lable><br>

    <input type="radio" value="2" name="Plan[packageId]">
    <lable>5 Games</lable><br>

    <input type="radio" value="3" name="Plan[packageId]">
    <lable>10 Games</lable><br>
</td>
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vk3z45an/

Comment: Open your console : `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=Plan[packageId]]:checked' `

Comment: There plenty of suggestions on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the CSS meta characters or wrap them in quote for preventing the selector from breaking:

```
var selectedPlan = $("input[name='Plan[packageId]']:checked").val();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nb32s47/)**

Comment: can u also edit the script to load the page by selecting a default value. the third item as default please.

Comment: using jquery `$("input[name='Plan[packageId]']:eq(2)").prop('checked',true)` http://jsfiddle.net/xzkgfL3h/

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `[]` characters in the name attribute of the selector (or wrap them in quotes) and remove the un-matched apostrophe at the end. Try this:

```
var selectedPlan = $("input[name=Plan\\[packageId\\]]:checked").val();
alert(selectedPlan);

// alternatively:
// var selectedPlan = $("input[name='Plan[packageId]']:checked").val();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vk3z45an/3/)

Note that you're running your code on load of the page and your HTML has no radio selected by default. I added a `checked` attribute to one of the radios so you can see it working. Also, your original fiddle did not include jQuery so I added that too. Finally, the element is `label`, not `lable`.

Comment: Also, run this on `radio` `click`

Comment: @Rory can u please create a js fiddle ? it doesnt work for me.

Comment: tnx, can u add the checked via jquery, without setting the html checked="true" pls

Comment: That depends on how you want to find the radio to set as checked. Have a search for it as there's hundred of answers on how to do that already.