# how to which radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html:

```
            <div   id="12hrs">12hrs</div>
            <div   id="24hrs">24hrs</div>
            <div   id ="none">None</div>
```

I assigned id i need to know which id to be selected?

Comment: why didn't you use input radio tag... <input type="radio" />12 hrs

Comment: In addition to above, Also use `name` attribute to group them then you can use `var value = $('input.radio_btn:checked').val();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: You need to give more info, like which lib you use to create a radio from the `<div>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/73hu8udv/1/

Comment: Is there any reason your radio button isn't an actual radio button? Ideally you should always write semantic markup and follow best practice. Trying to replicate an input element typically causes more problems that it solves.

Comment: It is generally considered necessary to at least attempt to solve a problem before it is posted on SO. Please show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign class something like this

```
<div class='temp'  id="12hrs">12hrs</div>
<div class='temp'  id="24hrs">24hrs</div>
<div class='temp' id ="none">None</div>
```

then

```
$(".temp").on('click',function(){
        $(".temp").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in favor of `.on()` years ago.

Comment: yes live is deprecated use on sorry