# How to determine if radio buttons are checked?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to get all the radio buttons by their names and check if they are blank. If one is blank, then form will show an alert and will not submit. If all buttons are filled then it will go to the "else" part and see whether the answer is correct. If it is correct, then it will show the right values in that page `<div>`.

It goes to the "alert" but, even if I select the radio button, it does not go to else part.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnDel").click(function() {
    var count = 0;
    if ($("input[name='ques1']").attr('checked', false) || $("input[name='ques2']").attr('checked', false)) {
      alert("Please Fill all the Fields");
    } else {
      //question no 1                           
      if ($("input[name='ques1']").attr('checked', false) || $("input[name='ques2']").attr('checked', false)) {
        alert("Please Fill all the Fields");
      } else {
        if ($("input[name='ques1']:checked").val() == 6) {
          count++;
          $("#answerques1").text("Your Answer is correct");
        } else {
          $("#answerques1").html("<p style='color:red'>Your Answer is incorrect</p>");
        }
        //question no 2
        if ($("input[name='ques2']:checked").val() == 4) {
          count++;
          $("#answerques2").text("Your Answer is correct");
        } else {
          $("#answerques2").html("<p style='color:red'>Your Answer is incorrect</p>");
        }
      }
    }    
  });
});
```

Comment: try .prop instead of .attr.

Comment: you are setting the element's attribute. :\

Comment: you should be using `$("input[name='ques1']:checked")` to check if the radio button is checked

Comment: @Sushil That will return the element if it is checked. It wont return any boolean results.

Comment: @Sushil It make sense if you suggest `if($("input[name='ques1']:checked").length)`

Comment: aw crap, selected wrong duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/596351/497418

Comment: yeah @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you're right. my mistake. we need to check the length.

Comment: Hello sushil problem here is that i want if they ques1 and ques2 are unchecked then it show alert to fill the fields and if it is filled then only it should go to the else part where it will check if answer is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.is(':checked')` to check if radio button is checked or not..

```
    if(!$("input[name='ques1']").is(':checked')  || !$("input[name='ques2']").is(':checked')){
    // Both are not checked
    }
```

Comment: hi sssilas777 this is not working.. I tried.. what else i can do... i want if they are not checked then to show alert.. please fill all the fields.

Comment: Why it is not working.. any errors? can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry sssilas777 .. this works... now.. My mistake.. It is working perfectly.. none other worked... thanks a lot.. i was doing this fiddler for hours . now.

Answer (score 0):

Change all of the instance you are trying to check the radio buttons checked property to the following code.

```
if (!$("input[name='ques1']").is(':checked'))
```

Doing it like you currently are `.attr('checked', false)' sets the property instead of reading it.

Comment: what if OP asks, why do i need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` ?

Comment: Edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: this is not working. i tried

Comment: thanks for the details...sssilas777 answer worked.. thanks again