# Is it possible to assign value of text-field to radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am providing multiple check-box and radio button when i enter any value in text field than the same value will assign to radio button and How it is possible using jQuery. Below is the image for reference. I am storing Question and multiple answer and i am going to store true answer out of them like shown in image.

[image: Example shown in image]

```
$data = array();
for($i=0,$j=1;$i<count($_REQUEST['quiz_options']);$i++,$j++)
{
    $data["quiz_Options".$j] = $_REQUEST['quiz_options'][$i];
}
$data["quiz_Id"] = $Quiz_ID;
$data["quiz_Correct_Answer"] = $_REQUEST['quiz_opt'];
$quiz->insertOptions($data,'quizoptions');

<input  class="col-md-4"  type="text" name="quiz_options[]" value=""/>
<input  type="radio" name="quiz_opt[]" value=""/>

//Here I want to assign my textfield value to the radio button when i write something in my text field.
```

[Please see the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhatt_axay/xe5wqoto/)

Comment: You have to show your html as well as the script that you written for accomplishing this. Cannot answer simply by looking at the image.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i guess we should also post solved issue img.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: No it's not match to my requirement.

Comment: can you show the input text box tag name?

Comment: <input type="text" id="txtId" class="col-md-4"  name="quiz_options[]" value=""/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach a keydown event to the the textbox and update the value of the radiobutton.

something like this(pseudocode):

```
$('#textboxId').on('keydown',function(){
  $('#radiobuttonId').val($(this).value);
});
```

Comment: Yes Arno I got it like this way but still some missing...   My first field is static on the page it gives me proper output, but when i click on add more button than it does not work the remaining field is generated with the help of jQuery

Comment: @Bhatt Akshay could you post your code in a jsfiddle so i can help you better?

Comment: i fixed it here: https://jsfiddle.net/0vgvg6g6/1/

Your problem was that your keyup event didn't fire on dynamically added elements look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Comment: What is data-rdb inside attr('data-rdb')

Comment: I added a data-Attribute(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) in your textfields that links to the radiobuttons. So we have a reference to the radiobutton

Comment: Its not working when i generate my last three text field using my external js file.

Comment: could you please check your console for error messages or make a jsfiddle where you recreate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a data attributes (HTML5)
[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data)
:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to on blur or onchange and should use one class for all dynamic textbox creation. try this code

```
<input name="quiz_options[]" class ="changesNo1" value="" />
<input name="quiz_options[]" class ="changesNo1" value="" />
<input name="quiz_options[]" class ="changesNo1" value="" />
<input type=radio value="" name="quiz_opt[]">
<input type=radio value="" name="quiz_opt[]">
<input type=radio value="" name="quiz_opt[]">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var test_arr = $("input[name='quiz_options[]']");
$(document).on('change keyup blur','.changesNo1',function(){
 $.each(test_arr, function(i, item) {
  $("input[name='quiz_opt[]']").val($(item).val());
  var d=$("input[name='quiz_opt[]']").val(); // your reference
  //alert(d); // This alert for your reference
 });
});
</script>
```