# jQuery selected value always 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Laravel with some jQuery for a webapplication. When I submit an empty form, I redirect back to the page with the old values filled in (`form model binding`), which all works as expected.

The problem is at the jQuery part. I have several sections which are not shown when the value of a radio group is `0` (unchecked), and showed when it changes to `1` (checked). This works fine when I fill in the page, but it bugs when I redirect back if I have a validation error in the form.

When I have a form error, and I get redirected back to the page with the old values filled in, and read the selected values of the radio groups, all the values are still 0. Why is the `val()` 0 even when the radio has a selected value of 1?

```
var r4 = $('input[name="configtype"]');
var s4 = $('#comprehensive');

initsec(r4, s4);

function initsec(radio, togglesection){

    console.log(radio.val());

    //When being redirected back to the page with the radio selected at the value '1',
    //console.log still shows 0

    if (radio.val() == 1)
        {
            togglesection.toggle();
        }
    }
```

**edit**

`var r4 = $('input[name="configtype"]:checked');` can't work in this situation because I'm using the radio field also in other places in my code where I shouldn't only get the checked value but instead of the checked value, thus not duplicate as far as I know (because I've read the `var r4 = $('input[name="configtype"]:checked');` a million times but that's not possible in my code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery)

Comment: @koshinae did an edit to explain why I can't use the given link (because I've read that exact but couldn't find the answer  ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radio` is a set of all radio elements not just the checked one so calling `.val()` will return the value of the first element in the set.

You can use `.filter()` to select only the checked item

```
console.log(radio.filter(':checked').val());
```

or

```
var r4 = $('input[name="configtype"]:checked');
```

Comment: This worked! I was trying to avoid using the second option because I had to use a variable without `:checked` in it, exactly what I was looking for