# Check if any number of check boxes are checked

Tags: jquery

I have many check-boxes on a page which appear like this, I don't know what the value is of these check boxes and as a result I don't know what the ID is:

```
<input value="78" type="radio" name="radio_tax_input[unit-type][]" id="in-unit-type-78">
<input value="90" type="radio" name="radio_tax_input[unit-type][]" id="in-unit-type-90">
<input value="3" type="radio" name="radio_tax_input[unit-type][]" id="in-unit-type-3">
```

I do know the names of the check-boxes though. I'm attempting to check if any number of these check-boxes have been checked, using jQuery:

```
var selected_type = $("[name='radio_tax_input[unit-type][]']:checked").length; // count the unit type selections

if(selected_type == 0){
    alert('denied');
    return false;
}
```

However my variable `selected_type` is always set to 0. Could anyone suggest why?

Comment: as it is radio button..max one radio would be selected...

Comment: True, I just need to check if one is selected though

Comment: working fine https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4440/

Comment: Checkbox is different from radio button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected_type = $("[name*='radio_tax']:checked").length; // count the unit type selections

                if (selected_type == 0) {
                    alert('denied');

                }
 });
```

Make sure your code is inside `$(document).ready` if you are not using any function

Hope this will help.

Comment: @Liam your code is also fine make sure your code is inside `$(document).ready` if it is not inside a `function` or you have added jquery reference

Answer (score 1):

```
var selected_type = $('input[name="radio_tax_input[unit-type][]"]:checked').length;
```

This works just fine.
JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfaw9vvt/

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to surround the checkboxes with a `<div>` then the following will work:

```
var checkboxes = $('#container').find('input');
var checked = false;
for(var x = 0; x < checkboxes.length; x++){
    var box = checkboxes[x];
    if(box.checked){
        checked = true;
    }
}
if(!checked){
    alert('denied');
    return false;
}
```

Working: https://jsfiddle.net/ojcv14v1/1/#&togetherjs=zSaKxCDtqI

Comment: Granted, this is longer than some of the other answers.  I guess you do learn something new every day.