# Selecting A radio buttons to add another input in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, textinput

I am trying to learn jQuery, by putting what I've learned into practice. So, here's my coding problem.

I have two buttons, one "yes" and one "no".  Once the "Yes" radio button is selected, a new text input is to appear.

my jquery below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#many").hide();
var isChecked = $("#dform input" ).change(function() {
    $("input[name=question]:checked", "#dform").val();  
  if(isChecked == yes){
    $("#many").show();
  }else {$("#many").hide();}
   });
});
```

my [code-pen](http://codepen.io/hnewbu1/pen/KrkjXP)

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery/596369#596369) added the value function in a variable, then used it in a conditional statement. I put the value `$("input[name=question]:checked", "#dform").val();` in an alert to make sure that the value attached to the "yes" radio button has been captured. However, when I put the .val() function in a variable and use it in a conditional statement, it doesn't work.

Did I set the Jquery up correctly?

Comment: *"Did I set the Jquery up correctly"* ... hit F12 on keyboard and look at ***console***. Will answer that question immediately by reading error messages.

Comment: I hit F12 and looked at console.  I see a big white space.

Comment: should see red error messages assuming this code is actually in your page and inside a script tag

Comment: In order for the "IsChecked" variable to ever receive a value, your function must "return" a value, i am not sure if on change events support this. Please see my answer as performing the change within the on change event makes more sense to me

Comment: @user3845646 it does already have  value and that is the jQuery object.

Comment: oh. not seeing them.  my code is all in codepen.

Comment: codepen must be suppressing error then because `yes` is undefined and will throw error

Comment: oh okay. but I don't understand why yes would be undefined even though I  set yes as a value in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your js with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#many").hide();
    $("#dform input" ).change(function() {
    var val = $("input[name=question]:checked", "#dform").val();  
     if (val == "yes") {
       $("#many").show();
     } else {
       $("#many").hide();
     }
   });
});
```

I'm sure it could be cleaned up more, but its working anyway. The jQuery set up is fine.
Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqxGmp

Comment: why would yes be undefined though?

Comment: @hnewbie You are correct! my original did not include the ":checked" attribute, so on page load the value would be undefined. Let me edit that!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#many").hide();

    $("input[name='question']").click(function () {

        if ($('#yes').is(':checked')) { $("#many").show(); } 

        else { $("#many").hide(); }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: With simple jQuery functions you can achieve this. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You're a little bit off track.  You don't need to name your onChange handler (`var isChecked...`) and I think that's confusing you.  I would try something more along the lines of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#many").hide();
  $("#dform input[name=question]").change(function() {
    if ($('#dform input[name=question]:checked').attr('value') == 'yes') {
      $("#many").show();
    } else {
      $("#many").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: so by putting the onChange handler in a variable, made the "yes" value undefined?

Comment: @hnewbie I'm not sure I understand your question.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: By putting `$("input[name=question]:checked", "#dform").val();` in the variable that I set, isChecked, did it make the value captured through the .val() function undefined?

Comment: @hnewbie if you did `var isChecked = $('#dform input[name=question]:checked').val();` that would have been just fine.  Your original code, had `var isChecked = $("#dform input" ).change(function() { ...`, though.  Later you tried referencing `isChecked`, but that variable was only assigned to your handler, not to the actual result you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to hide and show an element

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#many").hide();
 $("#dform input" ).change(function() {
     $("#many").show();
  });
  $("#no").change(function(){
    $("#many").hide();
  })
});
```

change html as:

```
<input type="radio" name="question" id="no" value="no" checked>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different way to do it simple way to do it with Jquery addClass and Remove Class method

```
**HTML**
<h4>
Click on button to toggle
</h4>
<div style="padding:10px;">
<button class="show btn">Show</button>
<button class="hide btn">Hide</button>

</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="name" class="displayN"/>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".show").click(function(){
    $("#name").addClass('displayB').removeClass("displayN");
});

$(".hide").click(function(){
    $("#name").addClass("displayN").removeClass("displayB");
})

});
```

Working Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mshyam83/u3wfpznn/