# Store data from HTML radio buttons into Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Could anyone please provide a JSFiddle Demo for me with an implementation?
I have the following HTML code below. I want to record in an array in javascript the the radio button I clicked. Say if I choose the first radio button `id="white1"`, the array should store the integer '1'. I am a beginner in javascript so any help would be appreciated!

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="overlay">
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="1" id="radio1"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="2" id="radio2"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="3" id="radio3"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="4" id="radio4"/>
          <input type="button" id="continue" value="Continue"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="base">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/event_0_Junli_Standing_20150322_181647_00_0.6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var arr = []
      document.getElementById("continue").addEventListener("click", function() {
          var cbChecked = document.querySelectorAll('[name="white"]:checked')
          if (cbChecked != null) {
            arr.push(cbChecked.value)
          }
          console.log(arr)
      }) 
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Why would you use an array to store a single value? (Or are those radios not part of the same group?) StackOverflow's [JS info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) has links to a number of JS tutorials.

Comment: The array will store other stuff too later on.

Comment: I can't anything that address this in tutorials.

Comment: better if you using class than id.

Comment: Ok sure but I want to store which one is selected; that's the main concern.

Comment: Hint: `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: In addition with @nnnnnn pass `value="1"` and so on for other radios.

Comment: did you read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery) ?

Comment: Ok thank you guys for the help I'll try doing it. I will let you know whether it worked.

Comment: @nnnnnn  Still very lost. I made a function that is called onclick with the continue button and added class="white" to all the radio buttons, not sure how to do the rest. function store(){ var x = document.querySelectorAll(".white"); }

Comment: To confirm, those radios are supposed be a single group, right? So only one can be selected at a time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to directly select whichever radio button is currently [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked):

```js
var arr = []

document.getElementById("continue").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var cbChecked = document.querySelector('[name="white"]:checked')
  
  if (cbChecked != null) {
    arr.push(cbChecked.value)
  }

  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="white" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="white" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="white" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="white" value="4" />
  <input type="button" id="continue" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

`.querySelector()` returns `null` if no elements match the supplied selector, otherwise it returns the first element that matches (in your case there would be only one). Note that according to MDN, [the `:checked` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) won't work in browsers older than IE9, in which case you might have to use `document.querySelectorAll('[name="white"]')` or some other element selection method to get a list of all of the radios and then loop through them till you find the one that is checked.

Note also that I've changed your HTML to a more "normal" implementation of radio buttons, that is, giving them all the same `name` attribute so that they work as a group, and giving them a `value` attribute to distinguish between them. They don't need `id` attributes - at least, not for this.

Comment: Do you think--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery--works better in terms of compatibility?

Comment: That other question asked for, and received, jQuery-based solutions, so you can't use those unless you include the jQuery.js library on your page. I've updated my answer slightly with links to some documentation at MDN. What I've shown should work in all current browsers, and in older browsers back as far as IE9.

Comment: Any reason not to grab the value "old school" using the forms collection: `var cbCheckedVal = document.forms[0]["white"].value;`? I'm guessing it would be more efficient than `querySelectorAll`, though not neccesarily appreciably so. If you were actually storing the selected element, as opposed to the value I'd see the benefit of `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @JonP - That *is* old school, but should be fine, yes. I guess what I've shown is a bit more generic, in that it works on elements not in a form, and can easily be adapted to work by class name or whatever.

Comment: @nnnnnn Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. I am not sure why the code does not work when I use it in my file, but it works here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @AlexKer - That error means that `.getElementById()` couldn't find an element with the specified id. The script element should be placed *after* the elements it wants to access. Try putting it just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @nnnnnn I placed the <script> tag right before the body closing tag, but when I go to console, it still shows up as undefined. Please see my updated code above. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest. I can't reproduce that problem.