# How to acces an array radio list element's value with Ajax

Tags: ajax

I have a form containing multiple radio lists like that:

```html
<div id="Question[180]">
    <input name="Question[180]" id="6" value="6" class="inputbox" size="1" type="radio">oui
    <input name="Question[180]" id="7" value="7" class="inputbox" size="1" type="radio">non
</div>
...
```

Reading that discussion [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery)
I thought accessing the radio value as

```html
$(\"input[name='Question[180]:checked'\").val()
```

but it always returns 'undefined'

How can I access Question[180] curent checked value with Ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code using `radio button name`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var radioValue = $("input[name='Question[180]']:checked").val();
    if (radioValue) {
      alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Question[180]">
  <input name="Question[180]" id="6" value="6" class="inputbox" size="1" type="radio">oui
  <input name="Question[180]" id="7" value="7" class="inputbox" size="1" type="radio">non
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$('input[name="Question[180]"]').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Question[180]">
  <input name="Question[180]" id="6" value="6" class="inputbox" size="1" type="radio">oui
  <input name="Question[180]" id="7" value="7" class="inputbox" size="1" type="radio">non
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake was just syntax problem. Correct answer is:

$(\"input[name='Question[180]']:checked\").val()