# How to verify if an input is checked and how to display it number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on star ratings. I reused code from Olga on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ad0v0/pen/LRJdAR). And I want to display dynamically the rate that the user selected like this : "You gave this product : 3/5".

I'm beginning in JS and jQuery so my ideas where limited ; I tried this just to test but it didn't show anything

```js
if ($('.rate2-star5').is(':checked')) {
  alert("checked");
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.css">
</head>
<div class="row">
  <fieldset class="rate">
    <input class="rate2-star5" type="radio" name="rate2" value="5" />
    <label for="rate2-star5" title="Awesome">5</label>

    <input class="rate2-star4" type="radio" name="rate2" value="4" />
    <label for="rate2-star4" title="Very good">4</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.2/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
```

Here what I want the result to look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEoOX.jpg

Comment: Hi @Nicolas, perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery) might help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following snippet that is basically derived from your original jQuery code:

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <fieldset class="rate">
    <input class="rate2-star5" type="radio" name="rate2" value="5" />
    <label for="rate2-star5" title="Awesome">5</label>

    <input class="rate2-star4" type="radio" name="rate2" value="4" />
    <label for="rate2-star4" title="Very good">4</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

You need to fire this code on click or change (of the value) of the radio button, then only you will see an alert.

Comment: It worked ! thanks.

So to display the rate I did this in the if statement : $('.rateValue').html($(this).val());

Comment: cool, so please select an answer to your question, if the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following jquery example I think it will help you.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.rate2-star5', function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var is_checked = el.is(':checked');
  alert(is_checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<div class="row">
  <fieldset class="rate">

    <input class="rate2-star5" type="checkbox" name="rate2" value="5" />
    <label for="rate2-star5" title="Awesome">5</label>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: add explanation on how this snippet will help and what fix were made from the OP

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work and I think that the solution from Code_Ninja is easier but thank you anyway !