# Direct to the specific pages among two buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, redirect, button

If I click the radio of debit_card and process payment then go to debitcard.php ,else I click the radio of credit_card and process payment then go to creditcard.php.

[image]

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="payment_item">
        <div class="radion_btn"> 
            <input type="radio" id="f-option5" name="payment_method" value="debit_card">
            <label for="f-option5">Debit card</label>
            <div class="check"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="payment_item active">
        <div class="radion_btn">
            <input type="radio" id="f-option6" name="payment_method" value="credit_card">
            <label for="f-option6">Credit card</label>
            <div class="check"></div>  
        </div>
    </div>

     <input class="main_btn" type="submit" value="Process payment" style="width:100%;"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/596369/8023799

Comment: <?
       if(isset($_POST['payment_method']=='debit_card'))
       {
       header('Location: debitcard.php'); 
       }
       else if(isset($_POST['payment_method']==credit_card))
       {
       header('Location: creditcard.php'); 
       }
                ?>

It does not work.

Comment: @BBb  Your radio elements are named "selector", not "payment_method"

Comment: Oops,I renamed it ,but still same problem.

Comment: And what exactly _is_ that problem?  Just saying "It does not work" doesn't tell us much.  What _does_ happen?  Please update the code in your question to include the `form` element.

Comment: Updated,thank you.

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: No one,alright!