# Jquery radio selection from this

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm seaching a way to do some thing like that in jquery

```
var my_radio = ("input[name='my_radio']");
my_radio.change(){
    var val = (this":checked").val();
}
```

How can I do this?
thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit this:

```
("input[name='my_radio']");
```

To this:

```
$("input[name='my_radio']");
```

And if you have multiple radio inputs, then you have to make this changes as well:

```
my_radio.each(function(){
    $(this).on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            console.log($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var my_radio = $('input[type="radio"]');
my_radio.each(function(){
        $(this).on('change', function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $('span').text($(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="4" />
</form>

<h1>You selected</h1>
<span></span>
```

Comment: yes sorry I forget this $ before ("input[name='my_radio']").

Comment: by the way it's better than to write

my_radio.change(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
  console.log($(this).val());
 }
});

what I was searching was how to write
in 1 times 
$(this).is(':checked').val();

Comment: No it's even more easy as I expected. it's simply $(this).val() because it's the checked who call the change()

Comment: and this would be the other answer myRadio.filter(":checked").val();
I just found the answer now on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery