# How to get the value of selected radio button where multiple radio buttons have same name using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

All of these radio buttons have an onclick method in which I am trying to get the value of the selected radio button.

```
<div id="interior">
<label><input type="radio" name="groundfloordropdown" value="125">1BHK</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="groundfloordropdown" value="175">2BHK</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="groundfloordropdown" value="225">3HK</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any onClick method...

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/596351/5104748

Comment: these radio buttons were created by another javascript method. The onclick method is not visible on inspection but is working as it outputs console.log();

Comment: So why you don't post all code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery to get the value by
`let value = $('input[name="groundfloordropdown"]:checked').val()`.

Comment: sorry for the wrong tag, i edited it, i wanted vanilla javascript

Comment: @Madhu, sorry, my bad, this can be converted to
 `let value = document.querySelector('input[name="groundfloordropdown"]:checked').value`. It will give you the same result

Comment: thanks a lot this worked out best for me better than all other answers

Comment: @LinhPhan you should [edit] your answer to include the vanilla JS version

Answer (score 1):

```
  var names = document.getElementsByName("groundfloordropdown");
   groundfloordropdown.forEach((ground) => {
                if (ground.checked) {
                    alert(`Choise: ${ground.value}`);
                }
            })
```

this is a pure js
**have a good day :)**

Answer (score 1):

Do **not declare** js events inside tags. This will lead to many bad consequences.

I made you a little javascript code using the `forEach()` method. This method is required to work with the *collection*. Namely, when you work with many elements that have the same **class**, or it will be the same **tag**.

Also, in this example you get the *value* of the `input` tag and the `label` tag.

If you have any questions, let me know. I will answer with pleasure.

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll('.radiogroup input');
let label = document.querySelectorAll('.radiogroup label');

radio.forEach(function (radio_current, index) {
    radio_current.addEventListener('change', function () {
        console.log('Value Radio: ' + this.value + '; Value Label: ' + label[index].innerText);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="radiogroup">
  <label><input type="radio" name="groundfloordropdown" value="125">1BHK</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groundfloordropdown" value="175">2BHK</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groundfloordropdown" value="225">3HK</label>
</div>
```