# How to use if..else statement on a radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this field at my form for calculating **Value Added Tax**:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form-product">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="vat" name="vat" value="on">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                Calculate VAT 
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="vat" name="vat" value="off" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label">
                Do not calculate VAT
            </label>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Now within jQuery, I want to check that if the radio button is set to the value **on**, do the calculation.

So how can I do that with jQuery.

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if($('[name=vat]:checked').val() === 'on')`

Comment: By the way you have invalid HTML there, the ID `vat` is not unique.

Comment: @CherryDT Can you show me the correct html format, plz

Comment: You want like this?
 $('input[val()="on"]').click( function(){do calculation}.

Comment: @Nikita Yes, plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a listener to get the value from the radio button.

```js
$('#form-product input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name=vat]:checked', '#form-product').val()); 
});
```

[Here's an example:](https://jsfiddle.net/RDA123/wxa8o6Ln/5/)

for more info in Jquery [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery)